# Vote cedo, vote frequentemente

Tags: debate, votos

Para mim, este é um post absolutamente necessário para ajudar o site se tornar saudável.

[Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) (um dos criadores desta plataforma de Q&A) postou há algum tempo um artigo com esse título falando da importância da votação. Leia: [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) <sup>(en)</sup>.

O **voto é a segunda coisa mais importante** para os sites SE (perguntas e respostas obviamente vêm em primeiro lugar). Você pode votar [entre 30 e 40 vezes por dia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/167534) <sup>(en)</sup>. Não desperdice seus votos e incentive novos usuários votarem.

Jeff também postou um artigo sobre como [fazer perguntas melhores](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) <sup>(en)</sup>. Por favor leia, e nos ajude a destacar a qualidade das perguntas e respostas com seu voto, separando o que não ajuda o site.

- Se você vir uma pergunta bem pensada, pesquisada e escrita de forma sensacional, **VOTE** - por favor! Grandes questões são uma arte!
- Se você vir uma questão sem esforço, escrita desleixadamente, ou que você sinta que foi feita de má-fé... **vote contra**.
- Se a pergunta está entre esses dois pontos e pode ser salva, **edite-a** ou sugira uma edição.

**Por favor, use os seus votos**.

Citando Robert Cartaino (gerente de comunidade) em um bate-papo há algum tempo:

> Vote, vote, vote. Encoraje os outros a votar, votar, votar. Em um
> bom conteúdo, deixe comentário ("Se você gostou deste post, por favor vote.
> É importante para a comunidade!") - Em ambos sites: meta e o site principal. Talvez alguns posts no meta possam informar os usuários da
> importância desse tipo de participação.

Isso é especialmente válido no começo da comunidade e com usuários novatos.

O mesmo vale para respostas. As melhores respostas devem estar acima das demais quando ordenadas por voto.

O direito de voto é um bem perecível. Você não precisa usar seus 40 votos permitidos todos os dias, claro, mas eles não são cumulativos. Então, quando você não vota, esses 40 votos não podem ser usados mais, mesmo que no dia seguinte você ganhe novos 40.

**Mas cuidado!** Não saia votando em tudo que vê pela frente. Vote no que você entende e cuja qualidade pode aferir. Votar em qualquer coisa a esmo sem nenhum critério ou desleixadamente pode ser pior que não votar.

O voto no site principal não deve ser usado para expressar concordância, é para demonstrar que a pergunta ou resposta merece crédito, por isso você deve conhecer sobre o assunto para votar.

No meta e em comentários, o voto para expressar apoio é mais comum e até desejável em muitos casos onde a comunidade está buscando a opinião dos membros, ou quando é melhor votar em um comentário do que escrever "+1", "concordo", etc.

E se você ainda não se convenceu da enorme importância do voto consciente, pode ler ainda outro [post do blog oficial](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/)<sup>(en)</sup> e essa [pergunta no MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)<sup>(en)</sup>.

---

A intenção deste *post* é funcionar como uma FAQ, porém seria útil entender porque as pessoas estão votando tão pouco. Estratégia para beneficiar o próprio conteúdo? A qualidade de quase tudo que há no site é não é boa o suficiente para votar?

Chega ser absurdo que após 10 dias de funcionamento do site, cerca de 93% dos membros nunca deram um voto sequer, e quase ninguém passou dos 40 votos (limite diário) ao todo.

Curiosamente, os usuários que têm as maiores reputações no SO têm os maiores [índices de votação](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all).

<sub>Em breve vou tentar resumir um pouco o que esse artigos linkados dizem para quem não sabe nada de inglês ou não quer ler tudo.</sub>

Comment: Ok, já "upvotei" sua pergunta.

Comment: "Upvotado" tb =)

Comment: O único problema é se o pessoal só votar nesse post :)

Comment: Leva um tempinho pro pessoal pegar a manha do site, porque nem todo mundo lê o meta e a FAQ. Lembro que no SO gringo só peguei o hábito de upvotear perguntas depois que o sistema me avisou que eu estava votando muito em respostas e em quase nenhuma pergunta. Dá um tempinho, que o pessoal vai aprendendo. =)

Comment: Meu upvote nesta postagem é devido a isto: >>> *Não saia votando em tudo que vê pela frente. Vote no que você entende e cuja qualidade pode aferir. Votar em qualquer coisa a esmo sem nenhum critério ou desleixadamente pode ser pior que não votar.*, muitas das reclamações dos últimos dias que talvez você tenha acompanhado é porque as pessoas não seguem isto.

Comment: Fez a pergunta direitinho e respondeu direitinho já tem meu voto. Quando todos perceberem que não custa nada clicar na setinha pra cima vamos ver mudança por aqui.

Comment: Pois é, eu vejo que o pessoal vota pouco, parece que comparam votar com dar like(face, etc). " -- Ah, não quero gastar o meu clique de ouro..." Não pense assim. Vote!  Principalmente se for uma pergunta plausível. Vote!

Comment: Além dos critérios acima citados para votação, eu levo em consideração se me ajudou ou não na solução do problema.

Comment: Votos negativos para *novatos* podem desestimular e criar uma barreira de entrada, logo, pode ser sugerido apenas editar e comentar, certo?

Answer (score 59):

Aproveito a "ressurreição" desta pergunta para atualizar alguns números. Quando ela foi originalmente postada, o site tinha 10 dias de vida, em beta privado. Naquele momento o @bigown apontou que 93% dos membros nunca haviam votado. Era um número expressivo, especialmente considerando que estávamos em beta, e que teoricamente a maioria dos participantes seria composta por gente realmente interessada no site.

Hoje, 16/03/2014, a situação parece ainda mais grave:

- **Apenas 252 usuários de um total de 6551 já votaram pelo menos <strike>uma vez</strike> dez vezes.

  Isso representa somente 3,8% do total de usuários.**
- Se considerarmos somente o mês de março, apenas 71 usuários votaram.

Para referência, o SO tem mais de 2,5 milhões de usuários, e cerca de 10% deles já votaram pelo menos uma vez. Parece que realmente temos um problema, as pessoas não estão votando!

Comment: Não me lembro de nunca ter visto uma forma eficiente de promover o voto... Bom, talvez deixar meta-posts sempre em destaque na página principal (cadê eles por falar nisso?). . . . . O que sim vale pra conscientizar à respeito da aceitação de respostas (e talvez incorporar o incentivo ao voto) é fazer um comentário: "Por favor, confira [Como funciona Aceitar uma Resposta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)". Agora mesmo, tem [1000 perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano) sem resposta aceita (uns 40%).

Comment: Caramba, 1000 é muito, realmente. Concordo sobre deixar esse tipo de comentário, tanto sobre aceitação, quanto sobre votos. Sobre os destaques, na coluna da direita da home do site *tinha* um box "Boletim da comunidade". Sumiu! Vou postar um *bug report*, não havia percebido isso.

Comment: Isso, "Boletim". . . . Acho que é um pouco pentelho ficar dizendo pras pessoas "vota aí, ô"... Dirigi-las à um Meta Post onde se explica o porquê me parece mais elegante, e aumenta a meta-participação ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Então, o comentário pode ser algo como "`[vota aí, ô](url desta pergunta no meta)`" :)

Comment: @brasofilo [Traduzi o faq sobre como aceitar uma resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078). Também já sinalizei pro Gabe atualizar o link da Central de Ajuda, que hoje aponta para o MSO, para a tradução em pt. É wiki comunitário, fique à vontade para editar.

Comment: Legal, marquei como favorito. Acabo de lembrar que dizer `+1 por este e aquele motivo, e além disso foo() é muito melhor que bar()!` é um bom motivador ;) . . . . . . **update** Corrigindo, [831 perguntas com 1+ respostas e sem resposta aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1..)

Comment: Como está isso agora @bfavaretto?

Comment: @JorgeB. Cerca de 5% de votantes.

Comment: @bfavaretto seria interessante fazer essa conta para usuários com mais de 200 de rep, que seria um meio levantar o número de votantes entre apenas membros ativos do site.

Comment: @Math Dá uma olhada [nesta minha resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1829/74).

Comment: Apesar de "ressucitada" e "bem antiga" (ao menos comparado com a maioria das perguntas), essa merecia entrar no "Em destaque no meta" no SOpt, pois esse tipo de destaque pode fazer os novos no SOpt entenderem a importância de votar...

Comment: Como vai isso agora @bfavaretto?

Comment: Não sei, @JorgeB.... a contagem é um processo manual chato, olhando os dados disponíveis na nossa página de usuários.

Comment: Estou achando que a maioria dos usuários, ou não possui reputação suficiente para votar, ou não possui reputação para votar contra, ou simplesmente se esquece de votar. Temos uma estimativa de quantos usuários possuem mais de 125 de reputação?

Answer (score 39):

Infelizmente algumas pessoas quase nunca votam. Existem casos de pessoas que recebem bem mais votos do que dão. Claro, fica na consciência de cada um. Alguns pensam na comunidade, outros estão mais preocupados só com sua reputação.

Mas agora estamos vendo uma fenômeno ruim. Por causa de um chapeuzinho bobo que vai sumir daqui alguns dias tem gente distribuindo votos a esmo sem nenhum critério.

Estes votos, em grande parte, serão revertidos porque o sistema detecta como fraude.

O voto é para ser dado todo dia, sempre que você acha coisa coisa útil, não é para sair estourando todos seus votos.

> Quer ganhar chapeuzinho? Ok, mas gaste um tempo para votar com convicção. Você ganha o chapéu do mesmo jeito e ajuda a comunidade ao invés de prejudicar.

Espero que essa atitude de hoje das pessoas saírem votando seja reproduzida em outros dias de forma consciente. O *site* precisa de mais votos, poucas pessoas estão votando e os que votam quase sempre votam pouco. Mas nunca deve ser em detrimento da qualidade da avaliação.

Detalhe importante: eu sou o maior beneficiário do mal uso da votação. Não importa, tem que fazer o certo.

Comment: +1 é mesmo isso

Comment: votei 920 vezes, 615 em perguntas(algumas favoritadas), 305 em respostas mas não ganhei esta medalha

Comment: @RicardoHenrique amanhã você receberá, caso contrário abra uma pergunta aqui no meta sobre isto. Espero que continue votando com quantidade e qualidade mesmo após ganhar a medalha.

Comment: Gosto de votar e favoritar(há algum limite?) sempre perguntas que são uteis (ou serão) e repostas que são/serão uteis ou muito bem elaboradas

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Só o limite diário. Favoritar é um controle só seu, não muda nada para a comunidade, já os votos ajudam classificar o que tem mais qualidade. Pelo menos deveria ser assim, mas a gente sabe que as pessoas votam no que gostam mais do que é bom, até porque elas não conseguem votar no que não conhecem e não farão isto no que não gostam mesmo que seja bom.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem um detalhe que pra mim, não tinha diferença alguma: o voto em resposta tem peso diferente do de pergunta ou vice-versa? Digo isso porque sempre voto mais em respostas sobre algo que eu não compreendia muito bem relativo a alguma linguagem, ou algum esclarecimento que, mesmo que não seja uma linguagem que eu domine, tenha entendido a explicação.  
Sempre achei mais útil votar em respostas, mas também porque achei que não tinha diferença votar na pergunta ou na resposta da pergunta.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe você pode votar como quiser, mas o ideal é que vote em tudo o que puder avaliar. Você leu, conseguiu julgar se aquilo está certo ou não, se é útil ou não para responder a pergunta, se tem fundamento, então vote, positivo ou negativo. Se não conseguir julgar, deixe de votar. Cada *post* é diferente, se vota em uma resposta, está votando nela, em nada mais naquela página. Normalmente o critério para votar em pergunta é um pouco diferente.Vote se a pergunta está compreensível,pergunta algo relevante e principalmente se acha que poderá ajudar outras pessoas.Este voto ajuda classificar

Comment: Engraçado, após comentar aqui, fui votar numa resposta e o site disse que "faz muito tempo que não voto em uma pergunta". kkk De qualquer forma, vou levar isso em consideração agora, pra mim, votar na resposta também qualificava  a pergunta junto, mesmo que eu não votasse nela.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes o voto na pergunta ajuda formar esta lista, ajuda as pessoas saberem se ali tem informação útil. Não é perfeito, tem coisas bobas com muito voto e coisas ótimas com pouco, mas acertar em parte é melhor que errar tudo. É comum as pessoas votarem mais em coisas que elas podem avaliar mais facilmente do que em coisas difíceis. E fazem outra coisa que aí considero um erro. Votam concordando ou não. Eu sei que isto nunca vai mudar, é comum a pessoa nem se dar conta, mas muito voto não é dado em coisa boa,certa,só porque a pessoa discorda

Answer (score 29):

A medalha de ouro de [**Eleitorado**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) está aí para premiar esse comportamento :)

*O que você está esperando? É fácil <sup>`*`</sup>, é rápido <sup>`*`</sup>, e, ao contrário do @perdeu, todo mundo ganha!*

[image: imagem da situação em Março de 2014]

<sup>`*` Lembrando que o voto deve ser consciente e responsável: vote somente em conteúdo de alta qualidade.

      Voto **negativo** também conta!</sup>

---

<sup>Taí o @elias que não me deixa mentir ([com sua medalha *Electorate* no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149872/elias?tab=badges))  :P</sup>

> <sup>[*no SO gringo só peguei o hábito de upvotear perguntas depois que o sistema me avisou que eu estava votando muito em respostas e em quase nenhuma pergunta*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente#comment553_159)</sup>

Comment: @perdeu, perdão pelo trocadilho fácil o_O

Comment: Boa paranomásia em "@perdeu, perdão" :) E olha, acho excelente você fazer esse chamado pras pessoas votarem. Mas infelizmente temo que tenhamos ainda menos usuários que acompanham o meta do que votantes no site principal. Então precisamos arranjar uma maneira de incentivar o voto lá mesmo, pois pouca gente vai ler isto aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto, fica pras gerações futuras ;) Eu aprendi um montão do [wordpress.se], do [so] e do [meta.se] lendo posts antigos.

Comment: Trocadilhos com o perdeu sempre vão existir né @brasofilo??? XD

Comment: @Gammeth, outro dia vc foi testemunha no chat, mas foi a 2ª vez que fiz um trocadalho com o *perdeu*. Não fico fazendo isso todo dia :D

Comment: @bfavaretto, acabo de encontrar a trilha sonora desta comment-thread, inclusive do Stack inteiro: [`perguntei tanto e ninguém nunca respondeu`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev07I9uGMcI#t=1791) | paranomásia poética no verso seguinte :o)

Comment: É a balada do tumbleweed :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, [*`balada`*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ixfG7.jpg)?

Comment: Hahahaha! Esse aí é o Clint Eastwood, @brasofilo?

Comment: Of course! Sergio Leone e Ennio Morricone na veia! @bfavaretto

Comment: O Leone está na minha longa fila de coisas que falta assistir ou ler... @bras

Comment: ah, não, uê, a Trilogia do Dolar com o Clint rodado aqui nos desertos de Almeria é pra assistir pelo menos uma vez cada década

Comment: Precisava [disto aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449/permitir-buscas-ignorando-acentuação), não só para busca mas para todos os autocompletes. @bras com arroba

Comment: Sei que é uma postagem antiga, mas acho que vai sempre ser útil, no entanto hoje temos *Concedida 47 vezes*, pra 3 anos de existência é pouco, imaginei que hoje teria no mínimo 200 concedidas :/

Comment: @Guille, che, meu velho, agora mesmo eu não sei se é falta de vontade ou falta de conhecimento... Você que frequenta mais, sente falta de algum "macaco velho" ali na lista dos 47? . . . . Topa fazer uma sala de chat Mega Meta BR? . . . .  se não agora, fica a idéia. . . . `(aos pt_PT, nós estamos na mesma casa, só que nós os _BR estamos em maioria :P)`

Answer (score 21):

**Campanha, "Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre!"**
Estou aqui para sugerir dentro do contexto atual uma campanha da nossa parte para incentivar o voto. Não sei até que ponto pode ser benéfico ou não para a comunidade, mas acredito que possa contribuir muito para que incentivemos os novos usuários e os que já estão estabelecidos na comunidade a votarem mais.

*Minha sugestão é que deixemos um comentário em cada pergunta e resposta com essa campanha e o link para esse debate do meta.*

> **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Aguardo seus votos!

EDIT: Como o @brasofilo falou, vai causar poluição dentro do site, acho que o debate poderia se focar em 2 pontos:

- temos como eliminar essa poluição depois?
- Vai trazer resultado?

Comment: Não entendi... É pra votar na Dilma ou no Aécio? :)

Comment: @bfavaretto como andam as estatísticas de votação do site?

Comment: Não, please... isso vai ser uma poluição visual danada... se isso acontecer eu vou panfletar minha própria campanha: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17564211#17564211 :)

Comment: @brasofilo é uma campanha boa pra perguntas e comentarios ruins :D

Comment: mas tenho q concordar, causaria uma poluição visual grande no site, mas acredito que os moderadores conseguem filtrar todos os comentários que tenham esse conteúdo e posteriormente excluir eles... @bfavaretto é possível?

Comment: Não, os moderadores não conseguiriam fazer isso, só os devs, direto no banco de dados.

Comment: Bom, então vamos deixar a comunidade decidir se vai apoia ou não a campanha, vou aguardar alguns dias para ver como vai andar a discussão aqui.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mais ou menos na mesma, veja: http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217103/votos-por-mes-no-sopt#graph

Comment: @Rodrigo, acho que o mais limpo seria a cada quanto tempo colocar esta pergunta em **[meta-tag:destaque]**, mas creio que isso merece um [meta-tag:novo-recurso] separado desta resposta aqui. Tem uma outra possibilidade, creio, que são os blocos de anúncios comunitários, mas tem que pesquisar melhor como é isso e qual o status aqui.

Comment: @brasofilo é um meio, apesar de que são poucos os que olham os destaques e poucos os que leem alguma questão no meta... o ideia seria poder fixar a campanha nas perguntas e posteriormente remover a mesma.

Comment: all right, mudei de idéia e reverti meu voto aqui, e ainda faz a resposta do favaretto passar pra primeiro lugar :D

Comment: haha, e só pra constar, por essa questão já podemos ver como as pessoas não leem o meta, temos 4 pessoas que participam do debate e 6 que votaram...

Comment: Meta, @Rodrigo, que Meta? Isso aqui é uma ilusão, esta `@notificação` não existe!

Comment: De fato o Robert Cartaino incentivava que fosse postado comentários para instruir a comunidade para fazer a votação. Eu acho que podemos experimentar e fazer uns posts em locais estratégicos. Só tenho medo de alguns usuários abusarem.

Comment: @bigown que tal fazermos uma publicação na wiki, explicando a campanha e dando permissão apenas aos moderadores para fazer as publicações, evitaremos um flood desnecessário com isso, teremos um controle das postagens e alcançaremos nosso objetivo