# Subtítulo Stack Overflow beta

Tags: suporte, status-pronto

Nas notícias falam que foi oficialmente lançado o Stack Overflow em pt e no site ainda consta o beta ao lado da logo.

Deveria ter sido removido ou ainda está em beta de fato ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está em beta. O plano original da equipe StackExchange era "já lançar o site de uma vez", por isso creio que eles se planejaram para tal, prepararam material de divulgação, etc. Mas na hora H apareceram um monte de problemas que ainda precisava resolver (o melhor exemplo são partes do site ainda não traduzidas/mal traduzidas), e o fato de só ter um moderador que fala português dificulta as coisas. Ou seja, no final das contas o site ainda é considerado "Beta Público" (semelhante à maioria dos sites que começaram na Area51).

Answer (score 6):

Complementando a respostado @mgibsonbr:

Existe a reputação mínima necessária para fazer algumas atividades. Quando sair do beta, esses limites aumentam e ainda não temos pessoas suficientes com reputação mínima para manter a comunidade saudável. Por isso eu reforço, [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente). As pessoas estão negligenciando esse aspecto.

Comment: Vi que esta resposta é antiga, mas como surgiu este post ontem: [pt-SO ads are outdated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317328/pt-so-ads-are-outdated), preferi não criar uma pergunta nova e apenas colocar um comentário aqui para avisar :)