# Por que as pessoas estão votando tão pouco?

Tags: debate, votos

Vejo que a média de votos em perguntas/respostas estão baixas, geralmente variam entre 1 e 2, sendo raras as exceções que recebem bastante votos. Por exemplo, acabo de receber a primeira medalha de pergunta notável ([link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4100/como-fixar-um-menu-horizontal-no-topo-da-janela-ao-rolar-a-p%C3%A1gina)), ela foi vista por mais de 2500 pessoas. Sei que muitos caem de paraquedas do Google, mas afinal, as pessoas estão votando pouco ou tem poucas pessoas registradas/membros ativos?

Geralmente eu dou um voto de estimulo a novos usuários, mas não vejo movimento da comunidade nesse sentido.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente

Comment: Verdade... As vezes escrevo uma resposta caprichada cruzando os dedos pra chover upvotes e nada. :p

Comment: "`Geralmente eu dou um voto de estimulo a novos usuários`" Acho que os votos deveriam ser dados baseando-se no mérito das perguntas e respostas, não como incentivo para novos usuários.

Comment: @Renan certas perguntas não são úteis para mim (seja por eu saber ou por não fazer parte do meu trabalho), mas isso não tira o valor dela para a comunidade. Se alguma pergunta não merece voto provavelmente não está de acordo com as diretrizes ou recomendações.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4166/estamos-com-problemas-falta-de-votos

Comment: Relevante ainda em 2019.

Answer (score 31):

Primeiramente, preciso dizer que compartilho com a sua impressão de que as pessoas estão votando pouco. Eu também gostaria de ver mais votos surgindo rapidamente nas novas postagens. Porém, resolvi colher alguns números, principalmente no [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE), e eles contam uma história um pouco diferente.

Se olharmos a [seção Usuários do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), podemos contar quantos usuários temos hoje. Na [aba votantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) podemos ver quantos já votaram pelo menos 10 vezes (que é o critério usado ali, ver o *title* da aba). Foi essa conta que o bigown fez quando [disse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente), na primeira semana do site, que apenas 7% dos usuários já haviam votado. Eu atualizei essa informação duas vezes, então temos registrado o seguinte:

```
data         votantes
-----------------------
2013-12-18   7%
2014-03-16   3,8%
2014-08-11   5%
```

São poucos números, e eles contam uma história parcial, porque muitos dos usuários não possuem sequer reputação suficiente para votar. Melhor então passarmos para os dados mais completos do SEDE.

#### Usuários votantes

Na situação atual da base do Data Explorer, temos **9722** usuários, sendo **2990** com [direito a voto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Desses 2990, **1619** já votaram pelo menos uma vez, e **499** votaram pelo menos 10 vezes. Seguindo a [sugestão do Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente/1076?noredirect=1#comment5307_1076), podemos também contabilizar os votantes entre quem tem pelo menos 200 pontos de reputação: de **415** usuários, **402** já votaram uma vez ou mais, e **317** já votaram 10 vezes ou mais. Sintetizando:

```
             Todos    15+ rep    200+ rep
-----------------------------------------
1+ votos     17%      54%        97%
10+ votos     5%      17%        76%
```

<sup>[Fonte dos dados no SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217167/usuarios-vs-votantes-no-sopt)</sup>

Entre os usuários mais ativos do site, nenhuma surpresa: quase todos já deram pelo menos um voto, e 3/4 deram pelo menos 10 votos. Mais interessante é notar que os usuários com direito a voto (15+ rep) representam menos de um terço do total de usuários do site. Isso condiz com uma outra estatística: a grande maioria dos nossos acesso vem de mecanismos de busca. E essa grande maioria não tem sequer 15 pontos de reputação, portanto não pode votar. Dos que podem votar, metade já votou pelo menos uma vez. Até que é razoável.

#### Votos por post

Fiquei um pouco surpreso: nossa [média de votos por post](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217799) é **2**, exatamente [a mesma do SO em inglês](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/217799). Não sei muito bem o que isso significa.

#### Votos por mês

Esse foi o dado mais interessante que eu achei. Nos meses de junho e julho, a quantidade de votos realmente caiu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[Fonte dos dados no SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217103#graph)</sup>

Pode ter sido por causa da Copa do Mundo, e das férias escolares no Brasil (supondo que uma parcela razoável do nosso público seja de estudantes). Os dados de agosto ainda são parciais, portanto não dá para saber se o número de votos tende a aumentar ou não.

O número de novos usuários também caiu, principalmente em junho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[Fonte dos dados no SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217317#graph)</sup>

Espero que essas quedas sejam mesmo por causa da Copa e das férias, mas teremos de aguardar para descobrir.

#### Votos por usuário

Ao calcularmos a razão entre a quantidade total de votos e a quantidade total de usuários, o quadro parece ser melhor. Estamos numa curva ascendente (embora desacelerando devido a junho e julho):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A curva é ainda mais íngrime se considerarmos na conta somente os usuários com 15+ pontos de reputação (de novo: os que têm direito a voto):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Conclusão

O site teve uma queda perceptível de movimento nos meses de junho e julho, o que pode ter causado a impressão de que as pessoas estão votando ainda menos do que já estavam. Teremos de esperar mais algus meses para saber se essa queda é uma tendência, ou se foi algo pontual. E parece que temos tido cada vez mais votos entre os usuários que mais participam do site. Isso é bastante positivo, mas não vem de graça: peço que continuem incentivando os votos, pois são uma das principais ferramentas para classificarmos a qualidade dos nossos conteúdos.

Comment: Sensacional! Parabéns!

Comment: Muito, muito bom, @bfavaretto. Vou tentar um esforço extra a votar nos mais novos (no site) que tenham boas respostas a ver se se tornam em membros com mais reputação e com vontade de votar.

Comment: Puxa, eu estava esperando uma respostinha em um comentário e vc escreve isso! rsrs.. Parabéns pela pesquisa, ficou estupendo, adorei os gráficos e todas essas informações. E ainda descobrir que qualquer usuário pode utilizar o SEDE para fazer queries interessantes. Muito obrigado. E obrigado também pela referência ao meu comentário :)

Comment: Valeu @Math. Quando você comentou, eu estava começando minha pesquisa para esta resposta, e decidi incluir os usuários com 200 pontos aqui. Pena que não dá pra saber os votos desses usuários por mês (porque no SEDE o `UserId` do dono do voto é sempre `0`).

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta @bfavaretto, o que percebi e que essa "queda" não é só aqui, quando conheci o S.O ficava impressionado com a quantidade e a rapidez que os votos aconteciam, agora por exemplo veja essa [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer) tem 9 mil views e 4 votos. Como disse o utluiz poucos votos mesmo com "proporções altas"

Comment: Excelente resposta. Junho e Julho foram realmente meses mais lentos, em diversos outros aspectos do site (estatísticamente falando), então não me surpreende que os votos tenham acompanhado. Ao mesmo tempo, a curva **ascendente** da participação *per capita* indica uma comunidade mais ativa, mesmo que em menor número, e a ideia do site sempre é essa. Quanto maior o site for, maiores serão as disparidades entre o "topo" e o "fundo" considerando que somos, assim como o SO, um site de *hit and run*.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta que fica ainda é: `Como fazer para que os usuários vindos de buscadores se registrem e se tornem membros ativos da comunidade?`

Comment: Avaliando subjetivamente eu vejo uma queda na qualidade dos posts nos períodos onde a votação caiu. Como muitos usuários tem a atitude de não votar negativamente (o que pra mim prioriza o indivíduo em detrimento da comunidade) em algo ruim, eles apenas votam menos positivamente. Não votar negativamente em post ruim é usar a ferramenta de um jeito diferente do que ela foi concebida. O ideal seria não ter posts de baixa qualidade mas como eles existem o ideal é a comunidade separar o joio do trigo e o negativo ajuda muito nisto.

Answer (score 18):

Realmente há poucos votos. E mesmo quando há mais a proporção não é tão "justa".

Somente para ilustrar, algumas de minhas respostas mais "simples" acabam ficando populares e ganham vários votos.

Por outro lado, já despendi algumas horas com perguntas mais complexas e tecnologias que não são tão populares para não receber voto algum.

A solução para isso está relacionada com o [artigo citado em comentário pelo @bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1813/por-que-as-pessoas-est%C3%A3o-votando-t%C3%A3o-pouco#comment5266_1813).

Acho legal a sua atitude de dar "votos de estímulo". Se o usuário é novo e escreveu uma resposta ou pergunta razoável, temos é que votar a favor mesmo, para mostrar que ele está sendo bem recebido pela comunidade.

Porém, eu acho que deveríamos fazer isso também com os usuários que já estão no site, de forma que as perguntas e respostas boas ganhem mais notoriedade. Por exemplo: existe uma resposta que mesmo não sendo escolhida pelo OP agrega algo? Eu votaria nela também.

Isso é algo que comecei a fazer mesmo no SOen. Antes eu via uma resposta boa com vários votos, utilizava o conteúdo e não achava necessário tomar nenhuma ação. Hoje eu vejo que é importante votar mesmo em perguntas antigas. Às vezes é uma informação que foi postada algum tempo depois e acaba não tendo a visibilidade que merece.

Outra coisa que antes eu fazia era não tomar uma ação quando uma questão já havia sido resolvida. Quando possível, eu tento votar na pergunta e respostas relevantes.

Algo que atrapalha um pouco é que muitos usuários não tem tempo de olhar todas as questões, então eles acabam vendo apenas as que chamam mais a atenção pelo título.

Hoje a grande massa de votos provavelmente é de uma meia dúvida de usuários que realmente dedicam-se ao site. Por isso eu sou a favor de uma campanha "pró-vote-até-acabar-com-seus-votos-diários". :D

Enfim, fora votar mais, também espero que a comunidade do SOpt cresça e essa questão acabe se equilibrando com mais usuários ativos. O tempo, a divulgação do site pelos próprios usuários ou pela equipe do DO em eventos, como foi no TDC, deve contribuir para isso.

Comment: Eu mesmo esqueço muitas vezes de votar, seja por pressa ou por estar focado em outras coisas. Talvez poderia ser interessante se o Stack Overflow desse mais ênfase nesse fator, colocar um aviso na página tipo: "Gostou da pergunta/resposta? Retribua com um voto", um banner ou algo do tipo.

Comment: É preciso entender que o SO funciona como um inesgotável banco de votos positivos, e é necessário fomentá-los para que a comunidade se mantenha ativa, e também estimule novos colaboradores, não os deprecie.

Answer (score 10):

Na minha opinião, como desenvolvedora, acredito que existe o fator da concorrência embutida, porque, também aqueles que contém um maior número de votos não votam nos demais, por simples fator de número. A comunidade para ter o crescimento esperado, tem que mudar a mentalidade, ando percebendo que alguns só sabem dar votos negativos, mas, não sabem dar um crédito quando as respostas merecem!

A guerra por votos não leva a nada, mas, o estimulo sim, ajuda e muito o crescimento.

Comment: De tudo que disse discordo apenas que os que mais receberam votos não votam. Basta olhar no [ranking de votantes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) que, em boa parte, quem tem bastante reputação tb deu um alto número de votos.

Comment: Respeito sua opinião @Math, mas, aparentemente é a minoria na minha opinião... e enquanto existir o fator ego amigo vai ser assim, no US é bem pior ...

Comment: Não posso falar pelos outros mas o que me impede de votar mais é sentir-me desconhecedor nalgumas linguagens. Raramente voto negativo. Concordo que estimular é melhor do que castigar.

Comment: @Math Nunca tinha olhado essa aba do *ranking*. O interessante é que se você multiplicar o número de votos por 10, a maioria dos usuários da primeira página já deu mais reputação do que recebeu. Tudo bem que tem os votos em perguntas, mas já é alguma coisa... :D

Comment: @utluiz exatamente! Costumo fazer essa conta tb, rs.. Dá para ter uma boa ideia de quanto de reputação a pessoa "deu". Fora que de toda a reputação recebida existem muitos +15 de respostas aceitas, que é algo a ser considerado nessa análise de proporção de reputação dada/recebida.

Comment: @Sergio também não voto se não sei se a resposta tá certa. Por isso acho mais fácil votar em pergunta do que em resposta. Se acho a pergunta interessante eu voto.

Comment: @Sergio eu acho considerável sua atitude, porque, isso mostra senso, parabéns ...