# Se acho que as outras resposta estão também consideravelmente boas eu dou um voto de confiança?

Tags: debate, comunidade, votos

Pegando o gancho dessa pergunta [Por que as pessoas estão votando tão pouco?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1813/11549), vendo que realmente acontece a pouca pontuação e por exemplo a grande solução do nosso OP @Sergio nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4100/11549), que teve grande votação (claro pelos seus méritos e clareza), pergunta-se?

Porque será que só uma resposta entre muitas teve vários votos, vendo que entres as 4, 3 me parecem corretas e poderiam também ter votos significativos????

Obs: Acredito que o Sergio é um grande cara nessa parte de Javascript e Css eu já andei olhando e é o cara que mais responde sobre tais assuntos.

Comment: Comentário rápido sobre a resposta citada do Sergio: das 3 que podem merecer votos, é a única que contém alguma explicação além do código que soluciona o problema. E para mim a explicação é mais importante que o código.

Comment: @bfavaretto como mesmo você disse para mim, e para os outros, nem sempre o que é bom para você é bom para os demais, democracia bfavaretto e muitas vezes palavras podem ser ao vento. Desculpa concordo parcialmente ao que você acredita, porque, no inicio de qualquer um de nós a sintaxe é mais importante do que a explicação.

Comment: Justamente: democracia! Cada um vota naquela publicação que achar mais interessante, a que tiver mais votos se destaca. E nada impede de votar em várias ou todas as respostas para uma mesma pergunta, eu mesmo já fiz isso inúmeras vezes, inclusive votando em respostas para perguntas que eu também havia respondido.

Comment: @Math é essa a pergunta, os destaques das respostas geralmente recaem nas mesmas pessoas e isso porque muitos votam na pessoa e nas respostas ... !!!

Comment: Se mais gente ganhasse [esta medalha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) (que [tem o nome errado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/961/medalha-esportista-deveria-ser-esp%C3%ADrito-esportivo)), eu ficaria feliz.

Comment: @Maria se os destaques das respostas caem sempre nas mesmas pessoas isso não quer dizer que existe uma preferência pela pessoa, mas provavelmente pelas respostas da pessoa. Se a pessoa já deu inúmeras respostas bem aceitas pela comunidade não é estranho que ela continue dando mais e mais respostas bem aceitas. Os autores das respostas que estão recebendo poucos votos se estiverem incomodados com isso podem passar a aprender com as respostas bem aceitas e mudar o estilo da resposta. Relacionado: [Quanto mais melhor? Ou um meio para dizer “se vira”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1531/3117)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu sou suspeito nesta pergunta pois a resposta referida é minha.

Porém o que tenho reparado que (como o [@bfavaretto referiu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1817/se-acho-que-as-outras-resposta-est%C3%A3o-tamb%C3%A9m-consideravelmente-boas-eu-dou-um-vot#comment5280_1817)) respostas com explicação são valorizadas. Uma combinação entre ser util, ter um boa implementação de código, conter explicação.

Votar em respostas certas, respostas que ajudam a resolver o problema e respostas que explicam e melhoram o conhecimento de quem pergunta (e quem lê) devem ser votadas. **Mas** devo lembrar que muitas vezes recebi nas minhas respostas comentários para melhorar a resposta, a pedir para explicar o meu código e para introduzir alterações sugeridas que melhoram o desempenho **antes** de ser votado. Como sabem não dá para saber quem votou em quem, mas eu tenho a certeza que muitas dessas vezes a pessoa esperou pelo meu edit e quando eu melhorei então recebi o voto.

Isto foi util para mim pois aprendi também a fazer de maneira melhor; foi util para quem perguntou; e foi util para quem lê à procura de aprender e talvez com problema semelhante. Pouco a pouco fui aprendendo a responder com mais cuidado (e quando o meu tempo livre me permite ser cuidadoso e pedagógico) e vi que essa maneira de responder dá mais votos. Tanto aqui como no Stackoverflow inglês.

A minha sugestão é: votem muito, comentem o código uns dos outros (de maneira cordial) e respondam sempre que as respostas existentes não sejam a melhor solução.

Comment: concordo com você em relação a explicação, acredito enriquecer demais a resposta. Apesar disso tudo, percebo respostas muito boas logo abaixo e esse é uma forma de dizer assim: Elas também não merecem votos de incentivo, até deixando um comentário educado abaixo, `amigo se poderia explicar para que eu entenda`...

Comment: @Maria Não tem regra para isso. Se você acha que outras respostas merecem esse voto de incentivo, vote. Eu faço assim (e não estou dizendo que ninguém deva fazer o que eu faço): se uma pergunta tem mais de uma resposta correta, voto naquelas que achar as melhores, que merecem algum destaque. Pode não ser nenhuma. Podem ser todas. É caso a caso.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu sei que não tem regra. Só estou fazendo um questionamento só isso... Só lembrando que eu venho do SO

Comment: @Maria eu também não estou te questionando, estou tentando te ajudar com informações e experiência. Não sei por que, mas sinto uma reação um pouco forte demais sua em relação aos meus comentários (vide o segundo lá em cima, na pergunta).

Comment: @bfavaretto claro, você já tem um opinião formada e não é me ajudar e ajudar o pt SO... aqui eu to para ajudar as pessoas e melhorar o entendimento e incentivar os demais, é aquele papo, a secretaria não é dona da fabrica, mas, ela é a cara da fabrica ... mais ou menos assim. Não rudez é responder a altura, pela experiência no norte americano eu não disse nada de mais ... !!!

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é ok votar em outras respostas boas e é legal incentivar a participação de todos os usuários (novos, regulares e veteranos). Nesse caso específico:

- a **primeira** resposta foi às **15:57**, de um usuário com 646 de reputação, 2 votos.
  Parece bastante completa, muito código, bem organizada e formatada. Mas não explica o porquê de nada, não tem comentários no código, não explica porquê resolve o problema apresentado.
- a **segunda**, às **16:01**, de um usuário com 1.679 de rep, 2 votos.
  Código curto e uma breve explicação.
- a **terceira**, às **16:41**, de um usuário com 16.000 de rep, 9 votos.
  Explicação exata e enxuta para resolver o problema apresentado. Código detalhado. Demonstrativo online.
- a **quarta**, no *dia seguinte*, de um usuário com 1 de reputação, zero votos.
  Tem uma pequena informação útil, mas é tão curta como um Tweet. Podia ser tranquilamente um comentário.

Me parece claro qual merece chuva de votos e quais um simples "ah, ok".

Acho que se deve votar na qualidade da informação:

- testou o código/recomendação da resposta e é útil
- leu o conteúdo e pensou "que legal isto, obrigado por compartilhar"

É *muito fácil* ganhar votos respondendo. É só analizar o trabalho dos Melhores Respondedores da sua tag de interesse, p.ex. [**`[jquery]`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/topusers), e copiar/adaptar seu estilo de formatação e apresentação de idéias.

Comment: Só uma opinião @brasofilo, o que não pegou bem na sua resposta é a reputação do usuário, eu acredito que isso recai no fator eu sei mais do que você. Acredito, também que isso faz uma recomendação que muitas vezes não tem lógica e não é uma situação que em todas as vezes o que tem mais reputação é a melhor resposta, ou até, um costume adquirido pela galera.

Comment: Você detectou o mesmo fenômeno com outros usuários de alta reputação? Talvez o público do JS/jQuery seja bem maior que outras linguagens, mas uma coisa é certa, o Sergio ***consistentemente*** escreve respostas de alta qualidade. Ali no exemplo que estamos analizando você acha que outras respostas também merecem +9?

Comment: A minha indagação foi que você fez uma comparação que não tem muito haver, pois, existe op com baixa reputação que são ótimo para comunidade. Naquele exemplo a gente percebe a falta de credibilidade dos demais usuários. Hoje mesmo respondi um questionamento e teve outra resposta com accept e que o op que responde faz um comentário não verdadeiro sobre um framework. Desculpa mas, +9 para mim tem o mesmo valor dessa que tem 0 e o accept!!!