# O Stack Overflow em Português é um site para programadores?

Tags: debate

<sub>Esta pergunta tem "cara" de ser um mero desabafo, mas a preocupação é legítima, e a questão foi postada depois de eu ponderar um bocado.</sub>

Antes de fazer esta pergunta, resolvi revisitar o **["Sobre"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/about)** do SOpt, para ver se o trecho a seguir ainda está lá. E realmente está:

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas.

O problema é que eu tenho notado que muitas perguntas ultimamente não tem sido feitas por programadores, e sim "fuçadores" (com o devido respeito) que pegam código 100% pronto, e trazem para o SOpt para que outro usuário faça remendos no código.
Isto que estou falando se aplica apenas àqueles casos de autores que perguntam coisas bem específicas, algumas até avançadas, entretanto de maneira que fica evidente que não tiveram preocupação de aprender o básico do básico da(s) tecnologia(s) envolvida(s).

Alguém poderia dizer que são **programadores principiantes**, mas na verdade não o são.

Programadores principiantes querem aprender, estão abertos a ouvir recomendações e a tentar fazer do jeito certo, reconhecem quando não dominam o que estão fazendo
e o mais importante: têm vontade de melhorar. Estes não me incomodam, pois com pouco ou algum tempo, evoluem.

**Importante:** Se você que está lendo acha que este post foi pra você, ou se "sabe que não foi pra você mas sabe de quem eu estou falando", **está completamente enganado**.

Eu não estou levantando este ponto por causa do usuário A, B ou C. Muito pelo contrário, se fosse um ou outro, eu nem ligaria. O problema é que na minha humilde opinião, há cada vez mais usuários fazendo perguntas no site
para economizar o trabalho de pesquisa, e simplesmente trazer a "tarefa de casa" para o site para levar ela pronta embora. E não me venham dizer que isto é bom, pois a qualidade das postagens tende a ser tão mal formulada que;

- o site fica tão cheio de ruído, que não conseguimos achar o que estamos procurando no meio de tanta bagunça;
- potenciais futuros usuários nunca vão encontrar o SOpt nos buscadores ao procurar pelo mesmo problema, dada a péssima formulação com que a questão costuma ser apresentada;
- ou, o que é mais comum, o problema é tão específico, que só serve para a pessoa que está perguntando;
- para piorar, o site fica cheio de semi-duplicatas. A dúvida às vezes já foi resolvida em questões diferentes, mas ao combinar diversos conceitos na mesma questão, atrapalha-se o fechamento.

  Nota: **duplicata é bom** para que o site tenha várias maneiras de se chegar a uma solução. O que **não é bom** é duplicata aberta, dividindo as respostas pelo site, de forma a você encontrar uma pergunta, e a resposta boa estar em outra pergunta que você nem sabe que existe.

Uma ou outra destas ocorrencias ainda seria aceitável, mas estão aparecendo perguntas que acumulam vários dos pontos mencionados. O que me preocupa é deixar que este tipo de pergunta continue aparecendo na progressão geométrica
em que têm vindo, a ponto do site ficar intragável.

A pergunta é: O site é mesmo para programadores profissionais e entusiastas? Justifica ter uma massa de códigos só pela esperança de sermos achados nos buscadores por termos quase que aleatórios? O que queremos aqui? <strike>De onde viemos? Para onde vamos? Eram os deuses astronautas?</strike>

- Se esta afirmação estiver desatualizada e/ou equivocada (favor usar argumentação concreta, pois retórica "não cola" mais), não tem problema, basta atualizar o **["Sobre"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/about)** para que reflita o rumo do site, para que todo mundo se oriente pela mesma bússola;
- se for pertinente o que estou dizendo, que a comunidade pise um pouco no freio antes de sair respondendo qualquer coisa só pela pontuação, e que seja mais criteriosa antes de votar positivo em perguntas feitas sem o mínimo esforço.
  Dá muito bem para ao mesmo tempo ser tolerante e atencioso com os novos usuários, mas firme o suficiente sem deixar virar bagunça quando se tratar de pergunta "torta".

Adendo importante: sempre lembrando que o que importa no final é que as perguntas e respostas tenham os votos dados de acordo com seu valor, independente de quem postou (o SOpt é um site de perguntas e respostas, e não de pessoas). A decisão, no fim, é sempre de quem vota, e não de quem pergunta/responde. Quem vota tem que saber muito bem seu papel, pois isto é o que define o site no final das contas.

<sub><sup>Nota do OP: Estou "passando a bola" para outros usuários do site se preocuparem mais, e eu menos, pois cansei de tentar fazer pessoas entenderem certas coisas e no fim o assunto acabar sempre sendo levado para o lado pessoal. Assim, por ora vou me limitar a tentar ajudar com uma resposta ou outra, e torcer para que vocês façam um ótimo SOpt para o futuro. ;)</sup></sub>

Comment: Sinceramente não tenho resposta para te dar... Mas sem duvida que a pergunta é pertinente.

Comment: Eu estou a pouco tempo acompanhando o site, pois eu sempre pesquiso na versão em inglês do SOF, e estava me perguntando a mesma coisa.
Por exemplo: por que essa pergunta ganhou 4 votos positivos? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/transformar-query-em-linq
O cara nem se deu ao trabalho de tentar.

Comment: A central de ajuda responde ao título desta pergunta: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7eJZn.jpg

Comment: Estava ainda agora criando uma perguntar aqui no Meta sobre isso. Até achar a sua, 2 anos e nada mudou :P

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes e relendo ela, não acho que mudaria quase nada se eu fosse escrever o "desabafo" hoje. A única diferença é que na época eu levantei o assunto na intenção de evitar que piorasse, hoje já é fato consumado, e eu simplesmene convivo com as consequências. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Rotular os usuários como isto ou aquilo não é produtivo – aliás, é contraproducente, basta ver como pelo menos uma das duas outras respostas abordou esse ponto. O que precisa ser levado em conta é a qualidade das perguntas (das respostas também, claro, mas aqui estamos focando em perguntas). Isso inclui avaliar cada pergunta individualmente, e também o contexto delas, ou seja, olhar algumas perguntas anteriores do mesmo autor.

O problema que gerou esta discussão é real: existem mesmo pessoas que usam o site como uma espécie de fábrica de códigos que elas não conseguem criar ou adaptar sozinhas. É comum que essas pessoas postem várias perguntas seguidas, conforme alguns problemas vão sendo resolvidos e outros vêm à tona. O resultado é uma série de perguntas geralmente confusas, e tão específicas que dificilmente servirão para outros usuários, ou como alvos de fechamento de duplicatas.

As ferramentas que temos para lidar com as perguntas (boas ou ruins) são votos, comentários e respostas. É claro que também é possível simplesmente ignorá-las, mas só recomendo essa atitude caso você seja indiferente à pergunta, incapaz de julgá-la tecnicamente, ou não esteja em condições de interagir com os outros de maneira civilizada. Quem tem uma opinião, para o bem ou para o mal, idealmente deve manifestar-se por um ou mais desses canais.

Eu sei que existe uma [preocupação grande em tratar bem os usuários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho), principalmente os novatos. É uma preocupação válida e necessária, mas talvez o receio de desagradar esteja impedindo alguns usuários de dizerem o que pensam na forma de votos contra e votos para fechar. Precisamos achar um equilíbrio. Não adianta achar que [ser sempre bonzinho vai tornar o mundo maravilhoso](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sbFhOeqTzY). Como em qualquer comunidade, há discordâncias. Isso é inevitável, mas prefiro as discordâncias sobre a mesa que embaixo do tapete.

É preciso que usemos bem as ferramentas que temos à disposição, e o voto é o principal indicador de qualidade. Não só é necessário [votar mais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1813/por-que-as-pessoas-est%C3%A3o-votando-t%C3%A3o-pouco), mas votar de maneira ponderada, ciente de estar usando uma ferramenta de classificação de conteúdos – não de pessoas.

Reflita antes de votar, mas não deixe de expressar sua opinião! É o conjunto de nossas opiniões que dá forma ao site. Se deixarmos o barco andar ao sabor do vento, uma hora ele pode adernar e afundar. E aí não será um ou outro grupo que sairá perdendo, iremos todos juntos para a água gelada, sem bote salva-vidas.

Comment: Acho que só discordo da recomendação quanto à ignorar um post. Me passou a impressão, talvez errada, de que é necessário opinar (votar, etc) sobre a maior parte dos posts que você vê no site, mas não encaro dessa maneira. Dito isso, acho que a parte mais importante dessa resposta é de que precisamos sim **votar mais**. Para o bem e para o mal.

Comment: Para registrar, eu acho que a nossa comunidade é muito respeitosa com as pessoas de maneira geral. Basta olhar o que é dito no Facebook, mais ainda no Brasil, em época de eleições. As pessoas se agridem das maneiras mais escabrosas, e isso não acontece aqui. De maneira alguma estou pregando o fim desse respeito, acho uma das coisas mais positivas do site. Só não quero que as pessoas deixem de se expressar por medo, ou por deixarem para depois e acabarem nunca votando. @Bacco.

Comment: @Gabe Alterei um pouco aquele trecho, mas a minha intenção ali é principalmente incentivar o voto. Não se deve votar em tudo que se vê, mas em tudo que de alguma maneira te chama a atenção, contanto que você tenha condições de avaliar o que está sendo dito (em certos casos eu não tenho competência técnica para poder avaliar, aí não voto; em outros, a pergunta não me interessa, aí também não voto; etc.)

Comment: Finalmente uma resposta para a pergunta proposta. É basicamente isto. Você captou bem a questão das pessoas ficarem com medo de fazer o que precisam fazer. Não podem ter medo de votar negativo quando o post realmente precisa ser classificado como algo negativo. E pior, algumas pessoas votam positivo para compensar um negativo que um post levou. Até aí tudo bem, muito eventualmente eu faço isto também. A questão é que precisa ser bem ponderada, precisa ser porque você realmente concorda com aquilo, não pode ser exclusivamente compensatório. Não pode ser para agradar o autor.

Answer (score 19):

## Pesque e Pague em Português

Eu já expliquei [em outra resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2005/12) o que penso sobre as tais perguntas que "querem tudo mastigado". Em resumo, provavelmente você está olhando para uma pergunta que apresenta problemas fundamentais de forma e função.

O que o OP espera, sempre, independente de quem seja, é uma solução 100% aplicável ao problema. A inferência que fazemos sobre o quanto de esforço o usuário fez *antes* de perguntar é, na melhor das hipóteses, um belo de um chute, baseado na forma como a pergunta foi escrita, como ela apresenta o problema, o nível de escrita e até nosso humor no dia. Não concordo que seja uma maneira confiável de se avaliar os rumos que um site está tomando.

Esse tipo de pergunta requer muito mais atenção e esforço por parte de quem for "mexer" nela, seja comentando, editando ou respondendo. É um vespeiro, por assim dizer. E ninguém é obrigado a aceitar esse desafio. Assim como se alguma boa alma acordar e decidir implementar todo um módulo de autenticacão em FORTRAN pra uma pergunta medíocre no site, parabéns! Ninguém vai ser o "profeta do apocalipse" só por ajudar alguém que fez uma pergunta ruim. Isso é ilógico e irreal.

### Tá aqui a tarefa de casa, professor

É uma questão de ponto de vista mas ao meu ver as tarefas de casa dizem muito menos sobre a personalidade da autora do que pode parecer. Fazer uma pergunta dessas provavelmente quer dizer, muito mais, que ela não está habituada ao formato do SOpt e **não pode** ser culpada por isso. É esse o tipo de pessoa que mais podemos ajudar. Os vários Lusófonos com milhares de reputação que permaneceram no SOen já tem um lugar pra si mesmos.

Mais de 50% das pessoas que já postaram no SOpt nunca participaram do SOen. É natural que não tenham absorvido as regras do site. Precisam de guias, paciência, instrução... E antes que alguém reclame, como **tudo** no SOpt, você fornece o quanto quiser. Ninguém tem que ciceronear um novato. Mas se você quiser editar e responder uma pergunta ruim **vá em frente**.

## Pague o aluguel

Dito isso sobre as tais "tarefas de casa", o site é para programadores, sim. Profissionais e entusiastas. Em sua maior parte, que nunca usaram o Stack Overflow e *não fazem ideia* do quão melhor o site pode ser quando comparado a fóruns aleatórios por aí. *Não fazem ideia* do que torna o SOpt melhor que vários fóruns por aí. Não entendem que nosso modelo é melhor, mais limpo, mais objetivo.

Isso é natural. Aliás, isso é o *esperado*, considerando nosso propósito com o SOpt. Sabemos que vários usuários vão passar por um "longo" período de adaptação, e erros serão cometidos, erros serão perdoados, até que tudo se encaixe. Ainda assim, como você disse, o ímpeto deve nascer do usuário. E eu concordo.

Mas **ninguém** vai criar nenhum tipo de apreço pelo SOpt, o tipo de apreço que o faria querer melhorar como usuário, só porque eu ou você dissemos que o site é lindo e maravilhoso. Não é assim que funciona. Se queremos que os usuários se esforcem pelo site, precisamos mostrar pelo que eles estão se esforçando.

Poucas pessoas permaneceriam no site depois de terem 2, 3 perguntas fechadas, sob a promessa de que "um dia você vai ver como esse site é bom, mas não hoje. Estude mais.". A comunidade precisa se mostrar **prestativa**. E eu sei que quando falo isso normalmente entendem que eu quero desvirtuar os últimos 6 anos sagrados, onde nenhuma decisão errada foi tomada, especialmente pelo Jeff, mas não é o que eu quero.

Há maneiras de ajudar alguém que fez uma pergunta ruim sem sacrificar a qualidade geral do site, dando à autora uma pequena recompensa *junto* da promessa de recompensas maiores. Esse é o modelo ideal. Temos 50 perguntas por dia, e bem mais que isso de usuários com mais de 1000 de reputação. Há como dividir a carga.

Ninguém é obrigado a participar, opinar e tomar conta de todas as perguntas do site. Confiem na comunidade. Confiem uns nos outros.

## Divirta-se

Agora, mais especificamente ao @Bacco, especialmente por conta do rodapé da pergunta. Eu vi que você tem 289 respostas, mas 0 perguntas no SOpt até agora. Suas respostas sendo úteis como são, com a reputação que te deram, indicam claramente seu nível de conhecimento sobre a área, que a comunidade toda agradece por você ter compartilhado.

Mas, ao não fazer perguntas, você pode estar abrindo mão de uma parte fundamental do site, que é conversar com outros ótimos programadores. Aprender com eles.

"Divirtam-se" foi uma das primeiras coisas ditas aqui no MSOpt. Divirtam-se. Conversem uns com os outros, perguntem e respondam. Não há a necessidade de controlar todo passo que a comunidade dá. Ela certamente não vai seguir tudo que você considerar correto.

Comment: Eu não discordo do seu texto, só acho que ele foge do ponto colocado. Eu gostaria de ver é a comunidade "moderando melhor" em vez de simplesmente votar sem pensar. Dá pra moderar sem massacrar. Diria que o problema é basicamente aceitar qualquer coisa de qualquer jeito, e não reagir de acordo. Eu, mesmo conhecendo o sistema, tenho dificuldade de achar o que eu quero no site, tamanho o ruído. Os mecanismos de organização me parecem sub-utilizados. Não tenho intenção de mudar o comportamento de quem pergunta, mas sim de melhorar o senso crítico de quem vota. O resto é consequência natural.

Comment: @Bacco A questão da organização é algo que faz bastante sentido. Que tipo de coisa você sente dificuldade em achar, por exemplo? E fica difícil encontrar porque tem muita coisa no mesmo assunto, por algum problema na ferramenta de busca?

Comment: A busca não tem problema e tem filtros. A qualidade do material ativo no site é que me parece duvidosa. Creio que quem pergunta tem sim que "entrar no esquema" (do site, não meu) e não o inverso. Em resumo, acho que o pessoal tem que ser um pouco mais empenhado em moderar do que incentivar postagens fracas. Nada impede de se fazer isso também educando o usuário a se adequar. Educação também é #carinho. E se o usuário não volta, provavelmente este site não é para ele. É a unica maneira que eu acredito que o site possa funcionar bem. Mas já compreendo que isto pode ser diferente da sua visão.

Comment: A "minha visão" importa bem pouco. Ou a de qualquer um, pra falar a verdade. Tudo que eu quero é que o site cresça e continue saudável. Crescendo ele está, mas o que você diz sobre ruído é algo que afeta a parte do "saudável", e isso sim é algo que eu preciso me preocupar, por isso as perguntas.

Comment: Eu usei o termo "organização" no sentido do filtro de entrada (fechamentos, edições, votos, etc) ser melhor usado pela comunidade, para que as postagens tenham uma qualidade melhor. Senão fico eu e mais dois ou três sendo os "chatos" do site, enquanto todo mundo vota positivo em qualquer coisa, e responde tudo sem pensar. E esses "legais" não percebem que a consequência a médio prazo tem um preço, que os "chatos" estavam tentando evitar desde o começo. Pra não prolongarmos demais, deixemos as opiniões aparecerem, e se achar relevante, podemos aprofundar isso num chat da SE em outra ocasião.

Comment: @Bacco Talvez parte da sua chateação venha da ideia de que você (e mais dois ou três) tem que "vigiar" todos os posts no site, ou de que todos os posts que você não acha que mereçam votos deveria ser fechados, ao invés de votados e respondidos. Como eu disse, esse site vai desconstruir todas as coisas que eu, você, ou qualquer um esperamos dele.

Comment: E este é o meu temor. Eu tinha algumas coisas para dizer sobre isto, mas depois desta, é melhor deixar pra lá. A política oficial deixa o site funcionar do jeito que for, se o caminho for barranco abaixo, que seja, ninguém precisa segurar nada.

Comment: @Gabe não é pessoal o problema, não estou chateado com nada. Estou pensando no melhor pro SOpt mesmo (deletei o comment anterior, mas vc tem acesso). Creio que não vai precisar, mas se for o caso, mandei um email com meios diversos de contato. Em resumo pode ficar tranquilo que a minha preocupação está longe de envolver interesse próprio, mas sim de melhorar SOpt para os usuários em geral (mesmo que tenha que botar alguns na linha).

Comment: @bigown Essa não é, nunca foi, nem nunca será a política do site. Mas eu não preciso falar isso. Todo mundo, inclusive você, sabe disso. Tratar as divergências como falsas dicotomias, como se apenas um dos lados pudesse estar 100% correto só serve para atrapalhar os debates que poderiam levar o SOpt à frente.

Comment: @Bacco Sobre esses "chatos", lembrei na hora do diagrama [dessa pergunta no meta.SOen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258663/520779)... :P (a pergunta em si também tem bastante a ver com essa discussão aqui, ainda que a "solução" proposta seja meio sem noção)

Comment: P.S. [essa resposta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/520779) explica melhor o sentido do diagrama.

Comment: @mgibsonbr acrescente um hated no link pros apáticos, acho que aí o diagrama combina mais comigo :P (só brincadeira, a coisa não é tão emocional assim ;) ). Gostei do achado, cabe numa resposta!

Comment: @Gabe gostei... Quando comecei, há uns 30 dias, senti uma certa dificuldade, por não conhecer o funcionamento do site, e no começo eu fazia perguntas que certamente me qualificariam como fuçador (que na verdade sou e acho até um elogio), mas aos poucos me ensinaram que também num é legal se fazer um tipo de pergunta que soa "faz pra mim".No geral esse modelo SOPT, nem se compara os outros, em termos de eficiência em esclarecer uma dúvida quando se tem... Gostei muito daqui, e acho o pessoal é bem maneiro e até divertido...Se existe um lugar para tirar duvidas de programação chama-se SOPT.

Answer (score 17):

Vejo muito mal uma pergunta dessa. É como uma tentativa de separar o que é um programador de fato de um "fuçador".

Existindo aqui vários tipos de públicos, há programadores de todo tipo: os iniciantes, os juniores, os plenos, os seniores, os hobbistas e os entusiastas, e não é todo mundo que entende como isso aqui funciona. Deixo meu contato pras pessoas me acharem no Facebook e vem gente dizer assim:

> "Ah, eu fiz a pergunta tal lá no **fórum**, lembra?"

Nessa hora, eu interrompo a pessoa na hora e explico que aqui não é um fórum. Aqui é um site de perguntas e respostas, que as pessoas entram aqui para resolver problemas e ganhar algum conhecimento, e isto torna aqui uma das ferramentas mais úteis do mundo, só que as pessoas não querem aprender a usar, ter o hábito de usar. Elas querem entrar aqui e ter o problema delas resolvido. Aceitem isso. Quem usa por hábito é uma minoria.

Eu vejo direto e insistentemente as pessoas colocando nos comentários "leia o link tal pra ver como o site funciona", e continuo acreditando que isso não resolve nada. São poucos os que vão ler. Quem lê normalmente é um usuário que já fez pelo menos umas 5 perguntas, que já tentou responder alguma coisa, que já comentou outras, que vai no chat e assim por diante. É um problema educacional mesmo. Aqui há uma cultura entre os frequentadores que todo mundo conhece bem as regras, mas não é todo mundo que é assim, e desejar que todo mundo seja é até contraproducente, se ainda quisermos estar abertos ao público que fala português.

Tem gente que frequenta o site há meses e ainda não aprendeu a aceitar pergunta, ou a votar a favor, ou até mesmo a **editar** a pergunta, que é algo elementar de tão básico. No início eu me dedicava mais a explicar como é o processo do site, mas tive que desistir de algumas atitudes que pareçam que estou pressionando o autor na pergunta em alguma coisa (por exemplo, pedir pra ele aceitar pelo menos uma resposta). Várias perguntas são tidas como "sem resposta" com meses de aniversário de abertura, mesmo que várias respostas respondam total ou parcialmente ao que foi perguntado.

A outra coisa que eu vejo é gente julgando o que é pertinente e o que não é pertinente perguntar. Eu diria que tudo é pertinente de ser perguntado. Pode até ser que a dúvida "não demonstre esforço de pesquisa", mas é preciso entender que o esforço qualititivo de pesquisa de cada pessoa é diferente. Há pessoas que sabem ir atrás de uma informação, e gente que nem ler em inglês consegue. Claro que eu acho um saco ficar corrigindo erro de português, pedir mais detalhes pro autor da pergunta, insistir em mais detalhes quando o sujeito diz que "deu pau", "não funcionou", "deu erro" e outras variações. Desde 2005 eu tenho que ensinar pras pessoas que a gente não tem bola de cristal e que a gente precisa de detalhes sucintos dos problemas, e isso é demorado pra aprender.

Acho que o Gabe falou muita coisa na resposta dele, e isto aqui deve ser considerado um complemento. Me causa repugnância certas atitudes, como, por exemplo:

- Mandar o autor da pergunta estudar;
- Fechar a pergunta porque a dúvida "não serve pro site";
- Mandar o autor da pergunta pesquisar no Google;
- Votar contra uma pergunta ou uma resposta e não explicar o porquê do voto;
- Segregar;

Aqui não é um panteão em que só entram talentos brilhantes, caras eminentes ou pessoas que só façam perguntas ótimas, recheadas de votos e explicações. O site tem vários propósitos. Ninguém começou sendo excelente no que faz. Todo mundo começou bem fraco e foi evoluindo.

Desculpem se fui muito prolixo.

Comment: Como discurso para as massas, eu acho que você escreve bem. Até gosto de alguns trechos, mesmo discordando de outros. Mas por enquanto vou esperar mais um pouco por uma resposta que fique mais no tópico da pergunta. De qualquer forma, grato pelo feedback. Quanto mais, melhor, para por o máximo de pontos de vista em pauta. PS: Foi longo, mas não foi prolixo, acho que a densidade x informação está boa.

Comment: Bom, são palavras de alguém que já teve dúvidas e que foi esnobado muitas e muitas vezes durante a vida.

Comment: Não concordo que qualquer pergunta seja pertinente. Você é realmente a favor de manter qualquer pergunta no site?

Comment: Eu sou a favor de manter toda e qualquer pergunta que possa ajudar alguém. Manifestar a dúvida é sempre pertinente, e cabe a nós como grupo arbitrar se a dúvida deve permanecer ou não. Pra isso existem os mecanismos de suspensão, exclusão, votar contra... o que eu me oponho é ao pré-julgamento de uma pergunta. Já salvei muita pergunta daqui que parecia perdida, e poucos que respondem vão por essa linha também, acho que pelo fato que é mais simples negativar do que ensinar a maneira correta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez ué... então você concorda comigo de certa forma. O que eu quero é só isso! Que se use os mecanismos de maneira mais efetiva. Acho que você confundiu a pergunta que o Gabe mencionou com essa aqui então.

Comment: @Bacco Quanto aos mecanismos, sim. Quanto a segregar usuários, não.

Comment: Isso é invenção sua, minha discussão não trata de segregar usuários.  Aliás, relendo a pergunta, acho que o texto tem material suficiente para ser entendido, desde que lido com atenção.

Comment: A invenção sobre o que é um programador e um "fuçador" é invenção minha? É uma taxonomia implícita, uma separação por comportamento. Portanto, não deixa de ser segregacionista.

Comment: Como sua opinião está devidamente publicada, apesar de não responder a pergunta (e nem estar falando do mesmo assunto), e aparentemente a conversa continuar a distorcer o assunto, vou me contentar em parar por aqui. Grato novamente pelo feedback.

Comment: Perfeito, Leonel.

Answer (score 6):

Sendo o mais simplista possível a **minha** resposta é:

### SIM

Detalhando um pouco mais digo que SOpt é um Site para Programadores. Eu diria mais, que é um Site com foco em Desenvolvedores. No seu próprio texto encontra-se a palavra **Entusiasta** e isso já engloba uma grande massa de não-profissionais que têm contato com o mundo da Tecnologia da Informação.
Além do mais, um Website é um...  um... ...nossa, é mesmo, é um Website. É acessível a qualquer pessoa que tenha internet. Isso inclui programadores profissionais, crianças fuçando em scripts de jogos, pessoas de mais idade (já to quase lá) postando em blogs, etc.

Quanto ao problema de perguntas muito básicas, é algo que também me incomoda, porém, aprendi a não levar isso muito a sério e saborear mais um gole do que estiver bebendo. O *Stack Overflow* , diferente de outros lugares que frequentei, possui as **ferramentas certas** para que perguntas a qual pareçam apenas postagem de gente preguiçosa sejam logo desencorajadas a serem respondidas (seja duplicata, mal formulada, despropositada, etc) e fazer com que os *perguntadores* melhorem suas próximas perguntas.

No mais, não havendo regras que forcem a quem pergunta ser um profissional de T.I. não há o que fazer quando não gostar de uma pergunta e ela não ser tolhida *out of the way* a não ser não respondê-la. Deixe outros usuários iniciantes ver seus nomes com o tick verde da glória. Afinal, não é gostoso quando isso acontece?