# Moderadores recebem algum tipo de remuneração, recompensa ou outra coisa para disponibilizar seu tempo para colaborar no Stackoverflow?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Essa é uma dúvida que eu sempre tive.

Vejo alguns usuários (a maioria moderadores) passando várias horas do dia fechando, classificando e editando perguntas. As vezes entrando em debate, etc...

Esses usuários disponibilizam uma grande parte de suas vidas para a plataforma do Stackoverflow. Vejo alguns o dia todo no site fazendo de tudo um pouco.

Minha dúvida é se esses usuários fazem isso por amor a sua profissão, por intenção de ajudar aos usuário (principalmente os mais iniciantes) que tem dúvidas, para melhorar (ensinando a melhor maneira) a qualidade dos profissionais da área, com a intenção de receber reputação ou simplesmente eles recebem algum retorno financeiro (ou outro tipo de retorno) da Stack Exchange.

Talvez pode ser em busca de reputação para, junto com seus conhecimentos e suas carreiras profissionais já estabelecidas, serem reconhecidos ainda mais através de uma reputação alta.

Essa não é uma crítica. É até louvável o quanto esses usuários ajudam aos iniciantes e o quanto de tempo eles disponibilizam para ajudar ao próximo. Se eles fazem isso só com a intenção de ajudar aos usuários, isso realmente seria algo lindo nesse mundo de hoje em dia, onde cada um pensa no seu próprio nariz.

É só isso. Uma dúvida que eu sempre tive...

Comment: Posso falar por mim: Não é profissão, não ajuda na reputação (muito pelo contrário, atrapalha, gera perseguição e inimizade), não ajuda na carreira (gasta tempo precioso). Mas tem gente que quer ver as coisas funcionando como foram projetadas para ser, e aí independe de "quem vai lucrar". De qq forma, não vejo futuro pra rede da SO/SE como um todo em relação ao que foi projetada para ser. Agora vive de fama só, o conteúdo anda muito ruim na parte de programação. Talvez outros sites, como o de matemática, até o de língua portuguesa, sobrevivam bem por não darem muiito espaço para paraquedistas.

Comment: O que você considera como 'paraquedistas' ?

Comment: Tá meio resumido aqui: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um site para programadores?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2096/70)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102692/discussion-on-question-by-jason-the-internship-moderadores-recebem-algum-tipo)