# A Stack Overflow e CMs sabem a diferença de "helpdesk" para as demais perguntas?

Tags: debate

Aqui no site alguns (a maioria que colabora de verdade) distinguem geralmente dois tipos de pergunta:

- Aquele que é um problema real do qual necessita de orientação técnica para aprender sobre como funciona;
- Helpdesk (ou suporte técnico), problemas específicos cujo o foco é ter o seu problema resolvido, não importa como, não importando entender como aquilo funciona e geralmente servindo quase como um Ctrl+C para "soluções rápidas";

Não sei se eu soube descrever bem ambos os casos, talvez eu ainda não consiga me expressar.

Voltando ao foco, sempre houve perguntas de helpdesk/suporte no site e incrivelmente às vezes recebiam respostas tão boas, que mesmo a pergunta sendo ruim ela ganhava muitos votos, mas este nem é o problema, o que tenho notado e ouvido falar é que tanto no SOpt quanto no SOen as perguntas do tipo helpdesk cresceram em um volume alarmante.

Eu entrei no site pela qualidade das postagens, isto em 2014, os fóruns que frequentei antes tinham graves problemas, há anos. Desde 2003 eu frequentava fóruns voltados ao mesmo escopo dos sites "stackoverflow" e realmente tinham postagens boas, mas raramente eram notadas e suporte técnico era o que mais tinha, fazendo boas perguntas ficarem no limbo.

O crescimento de "helpdesk" aqui no site tem causado a sensação de que estamos voltando a cair drasticamente na qualidade e o suporte/helpdesk tem se tornado o foco principal dos sites da rede de mesmo escopo, causando a sensação que estamos nos "tornando um fórum" comum sem interesse na qualidade e no bom aprendizado.

Muito ouvi reclamarem, mas me pareceu que muitas vezes a empresa e CMs talvez não tenham entendido ou talvez eles não vissem isso como problema. Gostaria de saber o que a empresa pensa disso, se o suporte técnico é um foco de interesse talvez ou uma estratégia para ganhar números e participação (mesmo que perdendo qualidade)?

Comment: Pelo jeito, eles não sabem a diferença.

Comment: Eu sempre leio, nunca opino, mas, essa respostas e comentários cabem bem no que você pergunta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2096/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-site-para-programadores?rq=1 de certo modo.

Comment: pelo que eu li aqui -> [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going) as métricas deles agora é quantidade de novos usuários, quantidade de perguntas, e mínimo de perguntas fechadas ou negativadas. Por isso parece me que eles estão a caminhar na direção oposta em que prezam quantidade e não qualidade, o que provavelmente vai virar full helpdesk. Eu não vejo isto com bons olhos não

Comment: Perfeita a sua pergunta!

Comment: @Diogo que bom que isso pode lhe dar um "norte" no entendimento, isso mesmo, espero que os demais usuários no site sejam pro-ativos como você esta sendo para entender aonde estão falhando ao perguntar e aprenderem como ajustar e aprender a perguntar para conseguir a ajuda necessária