# 8 anos de Stack Overflow em Português - recalculando rota

Tags: debate, comunidade, moderação

Eu sempre gosto de postar algo no aniversário do site, hoje farei algo diferente.

## Introdução

Não colocarei mais uma vez toda participação que tive no site muitos anos antes mesmo dele ser criado e como foi toda evolução, até porque o que interessa é o que ocorre hoje, e não é auspicioso.

Não é motivador, especialmente para profissionais qualificados, responder o tipo de pergunta que se posta hoje no SOpt, elas não vão ensinar nada para alguém, só interessa para o autor da pergunta e não gerará engajamento com outras pessoas, portanto vai contra a filosofia original do site.

O SOpt especificamente atende, hoje, um público que a gente conhece como sendo bem complicado pela baixa educação e falta de habilidade de trabalhar em comunidade, só querendo que seus desejos sejam satisfeitos. Cada vez mais isso tem se acentuado, praticamente matando o público que precisa aprender a programar e publica algo em que permita existir qualidade. De 2019 pra cá, principalmente, a queda na qualidade das perguntas é **muito** grande.

Atualmente o SOpt não ajuda a [internet a ser um lugar melhor](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/13/changes-to-stack-exchange/).

E houve um quase abandono total por parte dos usuários ativos que produziam qualidade. Percebo que as pessoas têm o mesmo sentimento que o meu.

## Mudança de postura

Então fiquei pensando se vale a pena tentar fazer o site manter a qualidade.

E acho que não vale. É **muito esforço para gerar bem pouco valor**. Nem mesmo o objetivo de impedir a baixa qualidade proliferar está sendo cumprido. Estamos enxugando gelo.
Não há nada que funcione.

Tem exceções agora, mas o grosso do conteúdo bom do site já foi postado no começo, e ele está sendo enterrado no monte de coisas ruins que vieram depois.

Porém, é o que tem, é o que as pessoas querem, mesmo que isso seja péssimo para elas, é mais ou menos como uso de drogas. Tem uma "meia dúzia" de pessoas que querem algo melhor, todo o resto não quer assim. Por isso acho perda de tempo tentar obter a qualidade. Se 99% não quer vacina não adianta vacinar.

Pra mim, só tem 3 possibilidades:

- encerrar o site;
- criar-se bem melhores ferramentas para lidar com tanta qualidade baixa, até mesmo impedindo que ela aconteça, fazendo os **programadores** gostarem novamente do site;
- tornar o site um mural de *helpdesk*.

Só posso interferir na última, e não me apetece.

Estou pedindo para todos refletirem, mas não para fazerem algo em específico ou mudar sua atuação. Estou apenas comunicando que eu vou mudar.

Continuarei no site e moderando, mas não visitarei mais quase todas publicações como fazia antes e não gastarei muito tempo onde visitar, por isso fecharei menos perguntas. Não vou me preocupar mais tanto assim das pessoas postarem coisas ruins.

Por favor, sinalize perguntas que deseja que sejam fechadas. Normalmente não é o mais adequado, mas se não tem gente suficiente na comunidade para fechar por conta própria, mesmo com 3 votos, e se um moderador ativo não ficará vendo tudo, a chance dela ficar aberta é grande. Se tiver sinalização eu fecharei, se pertinente.

## Futuro do site

Eu **desejo o melhor para o site**, apenas vou deixar o fluxo orgânico acontecer e parar de tentar segurar a água com a mão.

Eu sei que algumas pessoas vão adorar isso, mas é fazer festa em cima de um cadáver.

Eu queria fazer que esta postagem fosse um alerta sobre a qualidade duvidosa de muitas publicações (queria até colocar aviso em cada uma delas), mas sei que praticamente ninguém a lerá aqui, principalmente as que mais precisam, por isso nem caprichei, apesar da enorme importância.

Eu cansei a tal ponto que nem quero mais discutir o assunto.

## Meu futuro aqui

Ainda tentarei algumas ideias no médio e longo prazo, e moderando menos talvez volte postar mais em estilo (blog/wiki), tentarei ainda manter o site relevante de alguma forma, mas não vou mais tentar segurar o conteúdo ruim, não acho que esta deva ser a estratégia.

Eu realmente lamento pelo estado que chegamos, mas foge do nosso controle. Não acho certo abandonar a rigidez, mas não sou pago para fazer algo tão ingrato.

Sei que pode parecer, mas não quero que esta postagem seja uma detratação, pelo contrário, eu quero e farei o que eu puder para ser um novo ciclo visto da forma mais **positiva** que der.

## Conclusão

Minha atuação mudará bastante no ano de 2022 para frente. Não estranhe.

Eu estou aberto a críticas e sugestões, mas não mudará fundamentalmente minha decisão, ela foi muito ponderada, apenas farei ajustes.

O que vocês pensam? O que farão?

Comment: Primeira coisa que vejo, o grande mal da internet é a proliferação de cursos, apostilas e videoaulas elaboradas por pessoas despreparadas, incapacitadas e  que visam exclusivamente o lucro. Pois bem esses cursos guaipeca(vira-latas) estão formando em massa fuçadores de TI despreparados que ha alguns anos seriam escarrados de qualquer ambiente técnico mas que hoje proliferam em hordas chegando aqui no SOpt. A solução para esse problema vai além do escopo do SOpt que seria disponibilizar cursos de primeiro e segundo grau técnico em TI gratuitos na internet para combater os cursos.

Comment: Embora eu concorde eu acho que o buraco é mais embaixo, porque a falta de noção não é só de programação.

Comment: Por isso enxergo cursos de primeiro e segundo grau técnico em TI, como solução, não envolveriam apenas informática, seriam cursos multidisciplinares.

Comment: _"cria-se bem melhores ferramentas para lidar com tanta qualidade baixa, até mesmo impedindo que ela aconteça, fazendo os **programadores** gostarem novamente do site"_ - Eu consigo visualizar bem essa situação em duas fases do site: [a primeira é essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2096/70); e a segunda, atual, [essa aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxyBj.png)...

Comment: concordo totalmente com o que o @Maniero postou e acho que ele sintetizou bem a visão que as pessoas devem ter do que é o SO: **um mural de helpdesk**, as pessoas simplesmente tem um erro e não se dão sequer ao trabalho de ler a mensagem, ver se falta uma tag, um ponto, um tab... é desanimador. Não sou retrógrado mas, sou dum tempo que a gente tinha de pensar mais pq as coisas não estavam "claras" de "mão beijada"... se lia um livro e não tinha pra quem perguntar, era interpretar e testar, testar e testar até conseguir, esse mindset foi perdido, hj só querem tudo pronto, fácil e ainda ASAP!

Comment: até das discussões mais acaloradas que às vezes ocorreram aqui com algumas pessoas do site eu tenho saudade, pq eram discussões no sentido de melhorar uma pergunta, um entendimento, e nunca houve falta de respeito, apenas discordância.. já hoje, nem isso há, praticamente não há debastes, perguntas com multiplas respostas, pq na verdade são coisas tão pontuais se quere precisam de resposta, um comentário quase sempre resolve... eu mesmo de meses pra cá tenho respondido muito pouco, e não é desânimo, simplesmente não há o que responder que seja util pra comunidade.. espero o melhor para o site

Comment: ... mas me parece como o Maniero já comentou, enxugar gelo. Tem muitos sites com propostas semelhantes ao SO e há respostas pouco confiáveis, ruins ou com baixa qualidade, isso é que fez o SO ser o que é, uma fonte bem mais confiável, onde tem um banco fabuloso de respostas boas, bem formuladas e embasadas, mas isso vem se perdendo e estamos a nos tonar, novamente dizendo, um mural de helpdesk :(
desculpem o desabafo mas é bem isso que sinto, pouco motivado a ajudar quem não quer ser ajudado, mas sim que seu trabalho seja feito pelos outros. E para refletir, para onde vai a qualidade da TI?

Comment: @RicardoPontual acho que está correto em tudo, só vou reforçar que no começo não era assim, e destacar o que o Bacco colocou, a bola foi cantada, tinha que ter feito algo naquela época para não chegar ao que chegou. Gastaram muita energia em coisas bobas e esqueceram do que importava. Essa semana mesmo aconteceu algo nos bastidores que mostra isso, como não olham pro que realmente importa. Acho que os novos donos não sabem o que compraram, ou nós é que não somos espertos, porque o SOen tá quase igual.

Comment: Tens razão Maniero, esse assunto já rola no meta e o chat há um bom tempo. Sabemos que algumas coisas para serem mudadas é preciso mais que boa vontade das pessoas, a parte de administração do site tbm precisa estar alinhada, por exemplo na caso da sua sugestão, de ferramentas para fazer um triagem/analise/etc, é complicado realmente.

Comment: Eu concordo com tudo o que foi dito aqui. Mas vou fazer o papel do advogado do diabo ao lembrar que para o pessoal da década 90 para início do século a tecnologia da informação era uma novidade, um campo a ser desbravado,, tínhamos paixão em descobrir e era algo quase mágico fazer um código funcionar. A geração de 90 para cá já nasceu imersa nessa tecnologia, acho eu, pare eles é algo trivial, eles enxergam como só mais um recuso e o que importa para eles é se funciona ou não. Notem que não estou fazendo um julgamento moral, apenas estou trazendo um ponto de vista.

Comment: tens um ponto ai @AugustoVasques e isso tbm é reflexo de cada vez as pessoas pensarem ou serem inclinadas a pesquisa... olha mesmo a eletrônica, há tempos atrás, se uma TV ou aparelho de som dava problema, se pegava o esquema e testava componentes, descobria o/os componentes com problema e se arrumava, hoje, ou troca uma placa toda (basta desconectar a maioria das vezes) ou trocasse o equipamento. Isso é bom ou ruim? Depende, é prático, mas nem sempre tudo se resolve assim, falta o investigar, entender, aprender mais a fundo, isso IMHO

Comment: @AugustoVasques a análise é correta, eu vou julgar não só moralmente, isso é um erro enorme, pra elas principalmente, mas não tem o que fazer. É o mesmo que falar para as pessoas que dar esmola não ajuda ninguém, vai acontecer, foi por isso que tomei a decisão.

Comment: Não foi para mim, mas doeu como se fosse em mim, frase do AP: *Desculpe OP , mas você poderia me dizer como eu resolveria isso? Eu não sou da área.. fui pegando tutoriais e montando.* . Uma vez ou outra não incomodaria tanto, mas isso se tornou uma constante. Dai pergunto, existe a possibilidade de remover a  reputação mínima necessária para o uso do chat principal e encaminhar para lá o usuário de helpdesk? Propiciando assim a formação dum ambiente especifico e a parte do Q&A.

Comment: Quando é falado sobre a perda de qualidade no nível das perguntas, deve levar em consideração a grande quantidade de desenvolvedores júnior que entraram recentemente no mercado, que muitas vezes não sabem como pesquisar ou mesmo o que devem pesquisar. Inclusive, já estive nesta posição.

Acho que a moderação deve ser feita somente em casos de ofensas, perguntas fora do escopo de programação e afins.
Acredito muito em "darwinismo" das questões, onde a própria comunidade vai dar atenção perguntas importantes e desconsiderar outras.

Comment: O conceito de pergunta com boa qualidade é muito relativo e vai de acordo com seu nível de conhecimento. Me pareceu até um grande egocentrismo quando diz isso.

Mas tenho que concordar que existem perguntas onde as pessoas realmente só querem a resposta e irem embora, mas ai voltamos na questão do "darwinismo".

Acredito que o site tem o poder da orientação sobre os mais novos, e não sobre ensinar. Talvez seja importante avaliar uma mudança na postura.

Comment: A partir do momento que o cadastro é público, está sujeito a receber perguntas de "boa" ou "má" qualidade como você diz. Tentar evitá-las manualmente, é tampar o sol com uma peneira.

Comment: @Guilherme 
"*Acredito que o site tem o poder da orientação sobre os mais novos*" - Vou te dar o ponto de vista de quem já participa há alguns anos: eu e muitos outros já tentamos orientar de **várias** formas diferentes, e nenhuma se mostrou efetiva. A maioria dos usuários ignora as orientações, reclama que foi orientado ("*só quero a resposta*"), alguns até nos xingam. São raríssimos os que de fato melhoram a pergunta. Com o tempo isso desanima, desmotiva e cansa, e é um dos motivos pelos quais este post tem um tom tão pessimista - e também explica porque muitos desistiram de tentar ajudar

Comment: Até hoje eu ainda tento orientar as pessoas, mas a maioria continua ignorando as orientações. Sugerir que é apenas uma questão de mudar a postura, sem conhecer esse histórico, chega a ser desrespeitoso com os usuários que por tanto tempo tentaram melhorar as coisas. A minha postura sempre foi de tentar orientar, mas quem precisa mudar são as pessoas que não se esforçam o mínimo para fazer uma pergunta minimamente decente. É uma via de mão dupla, quem pergunta também tem que fazer sua parte. Não é só porque o cadastro é público que a gente é obrigado a aceitar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Enfim, sugiro que vc tente fazer isso por um tempo: orientar os usuários e ver qual o resultado. Se vc conseguir resultados positivos, pode compartilhar aqui no Meta, dizendo qual foi a abordagem usada (ideias novas são bem vindas), pois será benéfico para todo o site.

Comment: @hkotsubo o post não é sobre o que foi postando nos comentários anteriores, é mais uma tentativa de sequestrar um postagem para discutir o que já foi discutido diversas vezes, mas assino embaixo do que disse.

Comment: Olá @Guilherme sobre mercado, uma coisa é buscar aprender o básico, outra é querer suporte técnico gratuito para resolver coisas complexas do qual a pessoa ignora completamente as documentações que existem, quando eu era "junior", não existiam tantas docs e as que existiam muitas vezes continham falhas ou exemplos ruins, isso quando se quer existia exemplos, se observar diversas perguntas fechadas, são simplesmente tentativas de fazer o avançado, copiando coisas aleatórias, sem nem entender o funcionamento básico, não somos suporte técnico para "corrigir erros de uso e digitação".

Comment: @Guilherme muitos dos erros estão com a solução na própria mensagem de erro, mas a grande maioria não se preocupa em ler, um caso comum é o tal NullPointerException, quase toda semana tem uma pergunta de caso semelhante, a variavel não tem nada atribuido e a pessoa quer manipular ela, e já tem uma resposta detalhada sobre o erro especifico, que resolve para qualquer pergunta nova, mas as pessoas raramente querem aprender, o que muitas buscam aqui é suporte para corrigir seus erros, infelizmente.

Comment: Então @Guilherme antes de criticar ou sequer dar uma opinião sobre como um "grupo" deve atuar, é preciso conhecer os problemas reais e o porque o tal grupo (no caso os moderadores) devem atuar da forma que o fazem. Não são decisões aleatórias, são ANOS DE EXPERIÊNCIA com perguntas problemáticas e com tentativas para melhorar o site que deram certo e outras que deram errado, para formamos um "modo de atuar" e prevenir que o site se torne um local de suporte técnico, ao invés de ser uma fonte de aprendizado real...

Comment: ... Tendo interesse em participar para melhorar sua atuação no site e o site, é importante primeiro ler muitos dos conteudos postados aqui no META.

Comment: Eu estou vendo esse argumento *...O conceito de pergunta com boa qualidade é muito relativo e vai de acordo com seu nível de conhecimento....* ganhar ups, os incautos não percebem que é um argumento falso. O conceito de pergunta com boa qualidade é bastante objetivo, basta a pergunta cumprir o seu papel de comunicar e pontualizar uma problemática. Outros critérios são escopo e originalidade, o problema que estamos falando é fato das pessoas, em massa, não conseguirem comunicar suas necessidades.

Comment: Colocando em perspectiva para quem está chegando agora e já quer pular para a janela. Segundo os [dados da administração do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8708/feliz-ano-novo-2022) são [8 moderadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) para receber um contingente de aproximadamente 30.000 perguntas e 13.000 respostas num ano. Nos dois anos meus de Stack Overflow e percebo que são apenas uns 10 usuários da comunidade que ajudam constantemente e por volta de uns 20 usuários que ajudam de forma perene. Normalmente quem reclama é justamente quem menos contribui.