# Qual o critério da página de fazer pergunta para determinar a qualidade de uma pergunta? É possível melhorá-lo?

Tags: bug, perguntas, qualidade

Recentemente fiz [uma pergunta no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/542601/112052), e um detalhe me chamou a atenção.

Antes de salvá-la, apareceu um aviso no lado direito da página dizendo que a pergunta "*parece ser bem subjetiva*" e tinha "*boa chance de ser fechada*":

[image: Subjetiva? Sério?]

Qual o critério que o sistema usou para dar este aviso? Como foi feita a análise da pergunta, a ponto de concluir que ela parece subjetiva? *(O que seria, aliás, uma análise bem avançada, pois dá a entender que o sistema "entendeu" o texto)*

> **Obs**: o objetivo aqui **não** é discutir a pergunta específica (se bem que, dada a recepção da mesma, não parece ser subjetiva e muito menos bom "boa chance de ser fechada", mas enfim). **O que eu quero saber é: quais são os critérios que o sistema usa para mostrar os avisos descritos acima (e se é possível melhorá-los).**

Bom, neste caso específico eu ignorei o aviso, pois como membro ativo do site há anos, tive plena convicção de que minha pergunta estava OK (e novamente, dada a recepção atual desta pela comunidade, posso afirmar que estava certo).

Mas e se fosse um usuário novo, ainda não familiarizado com as regras do site? Este seria um gravíssimo falso-negativo (diz que a pergunta não é adequada, sendo que é), pois dá uma orientação completamente equivocada, deixando o usuário confuso (algo que, dada a [situação atual do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8706/112052), se torna mais grave ainda).

---

Curiosamente, esta mesma página, que parece ser **tão** inteligente (a ponto de detectar que um determinado texto é subjetivo), não usou esta suposta inteligência neste outro caso:

[image: Isso é ok? Sério? Não tem como melhorar mesmo?]

Ou seja, uma linha com letras aleatórias que sequer fazem sentido é considerada uma pergunta OK e o sistema não encontrou nenhuma maneira de melhorar. Mas uma pergunta legítima é considerada subjetiva e o sistema ainda avisa que ela tem "boa chance de ser fechada".

Afinal, quais critérios o sistema usa para chegar a estas conclusões?
E dados os exemplos acima, dá para ver claramente que está longe do ideal. Seria possível melhorar estes critérios?

---

Relacionado:

- [A nova página de fazer uma pergunta realmente será um sucesso?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8246/112052)
- [A nova página para fazer perguntas chegou!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8252/112052)

Comment: Mesma pergunta no Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/how-does-the-subjective-question-detector-work/27587

Comment: O falso positivo é bem pior que o falso negativo, se essa ferramenta relamente fizesse o que propunha, poderia diminuir pelo menos um pouco a quantidade de perguntas péssimas aqui