# Estamos com problemas? (falta de votos)

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, votos

### Intro

Tenho notado a pouca quantidade de votos positivos.

Como eu olho principalmente a página de perguntas mais recentes, sempre imaginei que fosse uma questão de tempo: perguntas novas não tiveram tempo de serem votadas.

Mas reparei e, hoje, confirmei que não é bem assim.

### Fatos

Escolhi 50 questões por página, e fui em uma página aleatória (primeira pergunta de 19/07 e última de 18/7).

Total de votos positivos: 43
Saldo de votos (total positivos - total negativos): 20.
Perguntas com 0 votos: 24
Perguntas com mais respostas que votos: 16

### Análise

Alguns pontos me preocupam, de mais para menos:

1. Perguntas com mais respostas que votos
2. 24 perguntas sem votos (quase 50%)
3. Média de votos (só contando os positivos) < 1
4. Saldo de votos médio é de 0,4
5. Das 24.979 perguntas (ei, estamos quase em 25k!), 9.905 têm 0 votos, das quais 4.844 têm respostas.

Bom, para o **item 1**, acho muito estranho... as pessoas **respondem mas não votam** a favor? A pergunta merece resposta mas não está boa?

Há quem vá dizer que quem respondeu pode ter votado, e houve outros votos negativos. Não é o que noto quando acompanho novas perguntas. A comunidade é sólida: se há votos negativos, logo a pergunta despenca com muitos votos negativos, ou é corrigida.

Além disso, era de se imaginar que uma pergunta que merece resposta mas tem poucos votos (digo, menos votos que respostas) teria alguma dica para melhorar a resposta. Nenhuma da página que vi tinha.

**Item 2:** Perguntas sem voto. Talvez esse item eu mais critique. Como pode uma pergunta não ter votos? Eventualmente, sim, mas é a maioria das perguntas na primeira página. Como diferenciar as perguntas? Como incentivar os autores?

Perguntas sem votos significam que ninguém se interessou. Quando são maioria, parecem *smell* de uma comunidade estagnada.

**Itens 3 e 4** mais uma análise, mas me preocupa: se os votos refletem a realidade, temos muitas perguntas fracas, e muito pouco perguntas boas! E se é só uma falta de votos, temos um problema maior: não dá pra diferenciar entre perguntas boas e ruins.

**Item 5** Mais de um quarto de TODAS as perguntas não tem votos. Nenhum. Bom, deve ter algumas onde os votos se anularam, mas isso me parece PIOR: houve interesse, e alguns julgaram a pergunta boa, outros ruim, e o debate parou!

Muitas perguntas sem votos foram criticadas, e corrigidas depois das criticas, e mesmo assim ficaram sem votos... Isso não incentiva a fazer boas perguntas.

### Conclusão

Minha razão para escrever isso é porque acho que não temos um problema de qualidade de pergunta, nem de quantidade ou qualidade de resposta. Tampouco acho que a comunidade falha em ajudar a corrigir perguntas e orientar os autores.

O que acho é que pouca gente se interessa em votar nas perguntas, puro e simples. E, talvez, muitos dos usuários estão à caça de **"perguntas que posso responder"**, não se importante se são perguntas boas, ou ruins.

O limite de votos diários é de 40 **por pessoa**... Vários dias, o **site inteiro** não chega a 40 votos, a não ser que o número de votos em perguntas mais antigas seja muito grande (o que eu não tenho como medir).

**Finalmente, o que quero saber é se mais alguém acha isso sério/problemático.**

Comment: Sobre o mesmo assunto: [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159/91) e 
[Vamos fazer uma campanha para incentivar as pessoas a votarem?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2510/91)

Comment: É, minha ideia é propor um mecanismo mesmo. Não dá pra recompensar voto positivo... mas pode haver outras jeitos.

Comment: @RSinohara na verdade dá para recompensar votos positivos sim, para isso temos a medalha "Eleitorado - Vote 600 vezes, com pelo menos 25% dos votos indo para perguntas"

Comment: Isso acontece no SOen também, já vi perguntas com mais de 50k views, várias respostas bem votadas, e sem nenhum voto positivo na pergunta!

Comment: E tem a medalha de prata pra 300 votos também @Math, esqueci o nome... Edit: essa: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty

Comment: É um problema de um bom tempo já ... que traz um outro que é meio evitado.

Comment: "mais alguém acha isso sério/problemático." Eu nunca tinha parado para analisar da forma que você analisou, eu já pensei em usar o [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) para fazer algumas análises mas nunca de fato parei para fazê-lo. Sua análise é simples mas achei excelente. Sua dúvidas também são muito intrigantes.. Parabéns pela iniciativa.

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que as pessoas estão votando tão pouco?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1813/3117) PS: a resposta do bfavaretto fez uso do SEDE, talvez seja a hora de rodar aquela query novamente para fazer uma nova análise e ver o que mudou daquela data para cá.

Comment: Acho que tens toda a razão o site está a ficar nivelado por baixo na qualidade das perguntas e o pessoal anda a cata de perguntas que possa responder. O problema existe. A solução é que não é assim tão óbvia...

Comment: Desconfio que o maior problema disso seja o fato de que a maioria dos usuários não se importa com a **classificação de qualidade** das peguntas e respostas do site, e só votam positivo quando a pergunta/resposta é útil pra elas. Pensando aqui em fazer uma resposta com meu ponto de vista, mas vai ser corrido hoje, então se não der faço outro dia... Até hoje, em pouco mais de 3 meses, já distribuí mais de 1k votos, e não acho que seja muito. Teve dia que votei 40 vezes (ganhei até uma medalha por isso! rsrs).

Comment: Existe esse problema sim. E muita gente ativa está deixando de votar por estratégia. Aí a consequência é que força outras pessoas fazerem o mesmo. E todo o site perde com isto. Se der tempo eu vou tentar fazer uma resposta ou pelo menos comentar com mais detalhes. Mas precisa ensinar os usuários novos votarem. Incentivar os "preguiçosos" e tentar mudar a mentalidade que quem não vota de propósito. Olha os usuários mais votados e olha os votos que eles deram, Tem usuário que tem um belo débito com a comunidade. tem usuário que teria muito mais reputação se retribuísse.

Comment: @rray fale do outro :) Eu acho que sei qual é.

Comment: @gustavox Na minha percepção, o problema não são perguntas pontuais com aberrações de votos... Isso pode existir. O problema é a maioria de perguntas com contagem estranha.

Comment: @Math Obrigado pelo comentário. Quanto a medalhas, não sei, mas suponho que a maioria seja como eu: medalhas não importam tanto (pra não dizer nada).

Comment: @JorgeB. e todos: A solução não é NADA fácil... Mas eu esperava confirmar aqui que o problema existe e tem impacto. Depois vou criar uma discussão sobre a solução.

Comment: @bigown eu no [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com) sou um dos que têm mais pontuação e o que mais vota. Ou seja, uma coisa não invalida a outra, é isso que todos têm de perceber. Mas a verdade é que vejo também muitas perguntas de muita baixa qualidade e nem apetece votar. Isso gera onde de "esquecer de votar". Falo por mim, claro.

Comment: Será que dava para fazer um gráfico com o votos ao longo do tempo do SOpt @Math?

Comment: @JorgeB. com certeza dá, a ferramenta do SEDE é sensacional, só não sou muito íntimo dela, to tentando tomar vergonha na cara e levantar uns dados já não é de hoje, rs.. Vamos ver se eu consigo em breve (hj não dá pois tenho reunião o dia inteiro, estou em horário de almoço agora)

Comment: Aqui também ocorre isto com a maioria dos usuários. Eu fico observando o comportamento de todo mundo que está na primeira página e alguns das demais. Tem casos claros que pessoas que votam por estratégia. De tanto ser prejudicado por isto, seletivamente eu comecei segurar votos em algumas pessoas, pelo menos, atrasando os votos. Mas tem casos de pessoas que cortei votos mesmo. Tem casos bem exagerados. Tem uma sub-comunidade específica aqui que evitam votar, talvez porque eles se achem melhor do que os outros. Não sei o quanto devemos lavar toda a roupa suja aqui. Talvez seja benéfico :P

Comment: @bigown o meta é mesmo para isso lavar roupa suja ;)

Comment: Quando eu disse perguntas de muito baixa qualidade falo no SOpt não no PL.SE @bigown

Comment: @JorgeB. eu entendi isso.

Comment: Uma solução seria criar uma nova categoria de medalha, categoria "diamante" que ganharia após 10mil votos, ou em vez de medalha, categoria "troféu". Fica a dica para o Gabe enviar um fax para os desenvolvedores da plataforma.

Comment: Esse ponto é um do que pensei bastante... As perguntas talvez mereçam, nem que em parte, a pouca quantidade de votos... Mas será que os votos precisam refletir o nível que queremos, ou mesmo comparando com o SOen? Eu penso que devemos votar medindo a qualidade média do site. O caminho para chegar em uma qualidade melhor não é cortar tudo que estiver abaixo da meta de qualidade. O que quero dizer é que a 'tara' da balança deve estar na qualidade atual, não onde queremos que chegue.

Comment: @Orion vou adiantar o que espero propor a seguir: uma recompensa diária para quem vota, uma recompensa por voto agregado (votar em perguntas que tem mais votos - talvez mais de 10), e limitar o ganho de reputação pelo números de votos (ganho de rep máximo = 10*o número de votos).... Vou abrir uma discussão pra reunir ideias, essas são só exemplos

Comment: @Orion ai saia toda a gente a votar a torto e a direito...

Comment: @RSinohara não concordo, se muita gente votar em perguntas de baixa qualidade elas vão parecer que são de alta qualidade e vamos acabar por nivelar o site por baixo.

Comment: @JorgeB. acho que não, se o cara ganha medalha votando 40 vezes, isso sim faria ele votar em qualquer pergunta porque o ganho seria imediato, mas ganhar após 10 mil votos, seria um trabalho de paciência, de migalhas, visando o futuro, "por que não um votar em uma pergunta que li" pensaria o usuário. Mas a ideia de medalha diamante é apenas uma "utopia" hahaha.

Comment: @RSinohara acho que o problema não está em ter gratificações para quem vota. O caminho para a solução é tentar mudar a mentalidade dos utilizadores, os novatos vendo que toda a gente vota frequentemente votam também.

Comment: Concordo, se fizermos a coisa mudar de direção com algumas pessoas, a tendência pode ser revertida... mas o difícil é começar essa bola de neve...

Comment: Eu penso que, de um lado, recompensa é o jeito mais direto de orientar um comportamento. De outro lado, mesmo quem tem intenção de melhorar o conteúdo às vezes não sabe bem como fazê-lo. Um incentivo constante não é só uma recompensa... é uma forma de mostrar o que se espera que seja feito.

Comment: Basta ver as edições... ninguém diria que editam para ganhar rep... mas os 2 pontos dizem claramente: é útil editar, se for bem feito.
Talvez muitas pessoas não saibam que votar é útil. Talvez pensem "votar é pra quem conhece o site, e vai saber se é duplicata ou não" etc.

Comment: @RSinohara também é um bom ponto de vista

Comment: @JorgeB.penso a mesma coisa, perguntas de baixa de qualidade e o pessoal respondendo de qualquer forma.

Comment: E vocês estão certos quanto a isso. Mas como eu disse, acho que pra melhorar temos que ver como está agora, e votar uma pergunta que está um tanto acima desse ponto... mesmo que longe ainda de onde queremos chegar.

Comment: @rray fale o outro, estou curioso haha

Comment: Já vi muitos usuários apenas comentando "Funcionou, valeu", "deu certo, até mais", e esses usuários já tem reputação suficiente para efetuar tais ações, entra como aceitar a pergunta como certa e upvotes

Comment: Entre os gráficos que fiz na pergunta que já linkaram aqui, acho que o mais relevante é o da [média de votos por usuário](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217819/votos-por-usuario-com-15-rep#graph), considerando apenas quem tem direito a voto. O número está subindo, nunca esteve tão alto, mas levamos alguns meses para nos recuperar da queda das férias de fim de ano.

Comment: Mesmo vendo o gráfico, eu continuo que a mesma sensação que todos aqui: de que precisamos de mais votos dos usuários ativos, e de mais usuários frequentes votando.

Comment: @bfavaretto e mais: havendo mais votos, minha impressão é que aumenta também a atividade geral.

Comment: Esses gráficos não medem a qualidade do voto :P

Comment: Concordo com isso plenamente! Estamos com problemas, acho que uma campanha para incentivar o pessoal a votar mais, quem sabe uma nova medalha ou algum tipo de incentivo seria cabível!

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu devo estar errado, SQL não é meu forte, mas o gráfico que postou não está dividindo os totais até o mês em questão? Não deveria ser só os valores de cada mês? Em outras palavras, os <= não deveriam ser só =?

Comment: Aquele gráfico realmente pega o total de votos acumulados e divide pelo total de usuários, @RSinohara. Praquela resposta, naquela época, achei que fazia sentido fazer isso. Hoje o mesmo gráfico está dando dados incorretos, por causa justamente do `<=`. Editei aquela minha resposta e retirei os links desses gráficos. Pra analisar a situação atual, acho melhor olharmos os por mês mesmo: http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217103/votos-por-mes-no-sopt#graph

Comment: Um exemplo é essa minha questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/601/como-organizar-a-numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-auto-incremento-de-uma-coluna-id-de-uma-tabela-no-mys Ganhei medalha de prata em visualizacoes, mas nenhum voto de formulação de pergunta. Apesar da pergunta ter sido útil, visto a procura que teve, somente as respostas receberam votos. Eu mesmo costumava votar apenas nas respostas, mas após um tempo como usuário passei a dar valor a quem formula questões que me são úteis.

Comment: Acho mesmo um ótimo exemplo de falta de separação de conceitos. Acho que ninguém votou a favor por descordar da prática. Mas a pergunta está inegavelmente bem formulada, clara, e pode ser respondida.

Answer (score 28):

Bom, aqui é lugar para opiniões, então darei a minha.

> Estamos com problemas? (falta de votos)

Não. A comunidade, a meu ver, está muito bem. Aliás, sempre esteve. A grande questão tem mais a ver com assiduidade de usuários do que com quantidade de votos.

[Peguei essa consulta do @bfavaretto pra ilustrar meu ponto](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/217167/usuarios-vs-votantes-no-sopt). [Tem também essa resposta sensacional, também do @bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1829/2999), que explica isso muito bem. A maioria dos usuários não entra aqui por hábito. A maioria não lê outras perguntas. A maioria vem aqui, tira sua dúvida e volta de vez em quando, quando precisa. Ninguém tem obrigação alguma com o site (exceto quem trabalha para ele e é remunerado por isso).

Opinativamente falando, se uma pergunta é útil, voto a favor. Se não tenho certeza (por exemplo, não é útil pra mim, mas pode ser útil pra alguém), simplesmente não voto. É muito comum nas tags que eu frequento as pessoas começarem uma pergunta com uma abordagem errada do problema, e mais comum ainda eu ter que responder explicando que a abordagem está errada. Cansei de fazer isso, e pelo jeito vou ter que fazer mais, porque tem usuário que aceita numa boa e tem usuário teimoso, que faz cinco perguntas sobre o mesmo problema e não desiste de ver as coisas de outra forma.

Agora, se a pergunta/resposta é ruim, imprecisa ou errada, voto contra. Evito de usar o voto contra porque eu sei que ele é muito desestimulante. Não conheço quem goste de levar voto negativo. Sempre dá pra argumentar antes de votar, mas tem horas que não tem jeito.

Ao primeiro link:

- Hoje, 23/07/2015, temos 18.510 usuários cadastrados;
- 6.130 podem votar (1/3 do total);
- 3.244 votaram pelo menos uma vez (metade dos que podem votar);
- 993 votaram dez vezes (um pouco mais de 1/3 dos que votaram em algum momento);

**Conclusão**: um em cada 20 votaram 10 vezes ou mais.

Agora, dos usuários com mais de 200 de reputação, 77% votou 10 vezes ou mais.

Como eu disse, o grande problema não é gente que não vota, e sim que as pessoas não frequentam o site porque possuem outras atividades.

> As pessoas respondem mas não votam a favor? A pergunta merece resposta mas não está boa?

Exatamente. O voto positivo é para quando a pergunta/resposta é considerada útil. Se respondo, não sou obrigado a votar. Voto se acho a pergunta útil.

> Como pode uma pergunta não ter votos? Eventualmente, sim, mas é a maioria das perguntas na primeira página. Como diferenciar as perguntas? Como incentivar os autores?

O @Gabe uma vez deu a resposta pra isso: [carinho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho/).

É conversar com o usuário, fazer ele comentar, escrever mais, explicar o problema... explicar que não temos bola de cristal, e que a comunicação é fundamental pra que todo mundo saia ganhando.

> Mais uma análise, mas me preocupa: se os votos refletem a realidade, temos muitas perguntas fracas, e muito pouco perguntas boas!

Sim. Fato. Isso reflete a qualidade dos programadores que falam português, a meu ver.

> E se é só uma falta de votos, temos um problema maior: não dá pra diferenciar entre perguntas boas e ruins.

Não. É possível. Temos perguntas ótimas com 50 votos (ou mais) aqui no site.

> Mais de um quarto de TODAS as perguntas não tem votos. Nenhum. Bom, deve ter algumas onde os votos se anularam, mas isso me parece PIOR: houve interesse, e alguns julgaram a pergunta boa, outros ruim, e o debate parou!

Acontece às vezes. Isto eu vejo como um problema: é quando o debate se torna maior que a pergunta. E a chance do autor da pergunta sair sem resposta e ficar insatisfeito aumenta.

## Conclusão

Não acho que seja necessário campanha alguma para se aumentar o número de votos. Não acho que os usuários assíduos votam pouco. Não acho que todo mundo é obrigado a votar muito. É questão de opção. Ninguém está aqui obrigado.

Comment: Um dos pontos justificando poucos votos é a baixa qualidade das perguntas. Ponto com o qual concordo. Mas a dúvida é: se as perguntas fossem melhores, seriam mais votadas? Ou em outro formato: todas as perguntas BOAS que aparecem recebem voto positivo? Eu acho que não. Esse é meu problema. Acho também que a qualidade das perguntas estão baixas. Mas sem votos, não vão melhorar. Nunca. Eu acho que seus pontos principais foram que as pessoas não são obrigadas a votar, e que a qualidade atual não merece votos. Eu concordo! Mas se há outra forma de melhorar a qualidade sem ser os votos, desconheço.

Comment: "Meu problema" no sentido de "o problema que me incomoda" :)

Comment: @RSinohara Então, só posso falar pelas tags que respondo. E não são muitas. Já vi muita gente entrar com um nível técnico sofrível, não sabendo nem aceitar resposta, e hoje em dia são pessoas que respondem super bem, usando bom português e na norma culta. Pra conseguir isso precisou de muita conversa, muito puxão de orelha, até que finalmente as pessoas engrenaram e passaram a tirar proveito do site e a ajudar os outros. No fundo: o lema do site devia ser ajudar os outros com qualidade. A meu ver, a votação não necessariamente indica que as coisas vão mal.

Comment: @RSinohara Mas te respondendo mais objetivamente, acho que a grande questão é educacional mesmo. E não vai só pelo nível técnico, mas comportamental também. Muita gente não aceita críticas, faz pirraça, leva o site como jogo online. Ok, incentivo pra votar pode ser algo legal, mas não vejo propósito em fazer campanhas de conscientização. Os usuários frequentes creio que já votam bem.

Comment: É, eu não sei qual seria a solução... eu só penso na premissa do site "Boas perguntas sobem, perguntas ruins descem" e vejo isso falhando quando 80% das perguntas tem a mesma pontuação após 2 dias.

Comment: @RSinohara Já experimentou fazer isso com perguntas que tenham seis meses de idade? Garanto pra você que a percepção é outra.

Comment: "Boas perguntas sobem, perguntas ruins descem", mas demora meses? Talvez seja um dos pontos onde discordamos, mas pra mim uma pergunta que não foi classificada antes de ir pra segunda página virou história. Não seria de todo ruim, se não fosse uma das premissas mais importantes do site: perguntas são votadas e as melhores se destacam.

Comment: Virou história nada. Muitas vezes fiz pesquisas no Google e caiu em material daqui.

Comment: Sim sim, por história eu quis dizer arquivada, no sentido que o AP não vai mais melhorar, e os APs mais novos vão desistir da pergunta. O objetivo do site é manter as perguntas, virar história quando disse não era de forma ruim.

Comment: @RSinohara Concordo como o Cigano, como já tinha dito, o melhor é educar os utilizadores e tentar elevar o nível do site, só assim se conseguem mais votos, porque teremos melhores perguntas.

Comment: @RSinohara olha esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76071/aplicativo-rodando-apenas-no-ie estou tentando fazer ver ao AP que a pergunta não está boa mas ele não entende porquê.

Answer (score 13):

Acho que as razões que levam uma pessoa a votar em determinado conteúdo são muito subjetivas. Vai depender, além do conteúdo em si, da personalidade de cada um, mas, principalmente, da "capacidade" de ficar admirado com esse conteúdo.

E imagino que essa capacidade de se impressionar com uma pergunta/resposta deva diminuir na razão direta do conhecimento do usuário. Porque no começo qualquer efeitozinho em jQuery já me deixava “O quê, que bruxaria é essa??? Tome +1!”, “OMG, como esse cara respondeu isso em menos de 5 minutos! Tome +1!”, “Como assim uma resposta melhor que a outra na mesma pergunta??? Que site incrível!!!  +1 +1 +1! +1 pra geraaaaal! rsrs

Hoje precisa um pouco mais pra me impressionar, mas claro que não é tanto assim. :)

Então acredito que **NÃO**, não existe um **problema** na comunidade quanto a isso. Mas acredito que existam pontos que precisam ser discutidos, e melhorados.

```
<devaneio>
```

E no meio deste post, agora mesmo quando revisava este trecho de cima, surgiu uma ideia: e se os votos fossem escalonados, tipo de 1 a 5(!)? Ou melhor, de -5 a 5! Ou melhor, uma classificação mesmo: Excelente, ótimo, bom, regular, ruim, péssimo (ou algo mais criativo! rsrs)… e cada uma das opções atribuísse um X de pontos. Alguém já pensou nisso? À princípio me parece uma ótima ideia. Assim o voto não seria algo 8 ou 80, e não expressaria uma total aceitação ou desaceitação ao conteúdo.

```
</devaneio>
```

Este obviamente é um post de opinião, mas tenho alguns dados para os quais queria chamar a atenção antes de passar para  a parte meramente opinativa, e alguns outros, a que queria ter acesso pra “fechar o pensamento”, se for possível.

1º - Apenas ⅓ dos usuários cadastrados podem votar, e acredito que isso possa ser **reflexo direto da baixa quantidade de votos em perguntas, mesmo em boas perguntas**.

2 - As estatísticas postadas pelo bfavaretto mostram que dos X usuários com mais de X pontos de rep, X já ofereceram mais de **10** votos. Mas 10 votos não é nada. 10 votos é pra dar num dia ruim, num domingo chato, com poucas perguntas no site e de mal humor (IMHO, sempre).

O que eu gostaria de saber é: Quantos usuários com mais de 1k de reputação já votaram mais de 100 vezes, quantos com 10k+ já votaram mais de 1000?

...

Bom, olhei agora as medalhas Dever Cívico e Eleitorado e é realmente <s>decepcionante</s> (escrevi isso antes de olhar :P) **ANIMADOR**!

Eu realmente achava que teria apenas 3 ou 4 concedidas, mas eis que tive uma grata surpresa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode não parecer muito, mas 95 pessoas parecem estar bastante engajadas com o site, afinal, votaram mais de 300 vezes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E também não acho pouco. Imaginava, pelo que notei de alguns comentários, que seriam apenas 3 ou 4.

Fique claro que não estou direcionando esta crítica pra ninguém especificamente. Até olhei as stats do Cigano pra ter ideia de quanto vota um cara que vota pouco, e achei que ... ele tá louco! rsrs

1.731 votos!

Nada como o @Sergio, com impressionantes 4754, ou do @Bigown, com 7.449(!), mas achei que está muito bom. Como disse no começo, isso vai da personalidade de cada um, e não se pode **exigir** nada de ninguém, quanto mais um **voto**.

Mas tem um ponto que eu queria entrar, que é o seguinte: o voto é útil pra comunidade, na medida em que é usado pra **classificar os conteúdos do site**. Então, na minha opinião, não é preciso um “Vish, que pergunta legal!”, ou um “Nossa, que resposta sensacional”, pra dar um voto positivo (claro que seria melhor o sistema que sugeri acima, mas enquanto ele não vêm… :)).

Este voto indica apenas que você considera que o conteúdo **atende às exigências de qualidade do site**, que este conteúdo acrescenta ao site, que é positivo.

Não é um Nobel, é só um voto na qualidade da pergunta.

Não é possível que um conteúdo bem escrito, bem formatado, que resolveu o problema de alguém, e que por acaso você acabou vendo por algum motivo, não mereça seu +1. Que você tenha **coragem** de sair da página e DESPREZAR aquele bom conteúdo da mesma forma que desprezou um conteúdo medíocre. Isso é um absurdo.

E nem vou me aprofundar neste assunto - porque realmente não estou acreditando que isso exista - de um top user não votar num bom conteúdo de outro, pra não aumentar a reputação da “concorrência”.

Só vou dizer o seguinte: se isso realmente existir, é algo péssimo para o site, porque compromete toda a classificação do conteúdo, e coloca em xeque o próprio sistema de gamification...

**Sobre meus critérios de votação**

Acredito que a maior parte dos meus votos foi dada na época em que mais editei posts. Então não era difícil, depois de editar absurdos, votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que atendesse a um mínimo de qualidade.

Eu abria pra ver se tinha algo relevante pra editar, e só de não ter...  bum, tomava +1. :-) Hoje já estou um pouco mais seletivo, e também não vejo mais tantas perguntas como na época em que fiquei (ainda mais) “imerso” por aqui, logo não voto tanto, mas vou tentar mostrar a forma de votar de um user que:

i) é novato em programação; 
ii) que pergunta mais do que responde (na verdade agora to empatado, mas isso deve mudar drasticamente assim que passar do desenvolvimento pra produção do meu projeto), e que;
iii) DEPENDE do SOpt pra atingir um objetivo (a construção do meu site).

**Minhas razões para votar positivo**

**1 - A pergunta/reposta foi útil pra mim**

Dispensa comentários, e além do voto positivo também “ganha” uma favoritada.

**2 - Usuário com alta reputação fez a pergunta ou a resposta**

Se, no caso, a pergunta for de um novato, e tiver uma resposta de um usuário de alta reputação, a pergunta já levará +1 (e de repente uma editada se for preciso) só por isso (porque se um usuário de alta reputação respondeu, então a pergunta é boa).

É claro que eu leio a pergunta, leio a resposta, e voto mesmo que não entenda completamente, mas nunca sem pelo menos ter tentado entender antes, e julgar a qualidade da pergunta/resposta.

**3 - Texto da pergunta claro e dentro do escopo**

Mesmo que eu não entenda nada da linguagem, se eu tiver aberto a pergunta por qualquer motivo (pensando em editar, ou simplesmente por ter achado o assunto interessante), pelo menos a pergunta levará +1, e eventual resposta apenas não levará se for  i) de usuário novo, ii) não tiver ainda nenhum voto, iii) eu não tiver entendido nada.

Para as respostas sempre fui um pouco mais seletivo (e hoje sou muito mais), e dependerá da qualidade técnica, então muitas vezes, por eu não ter como avaliar tecnicamente, acabo deixando de votar. A exceção é quando se trata de um usuário com tamanha reputação que de tanto ver ele acertar (vou dar um exemplo vai: o @Sergio ou o bfavaretto em JavaScript p.ex.) tenho certeza de que a resposta está certa, mesmo sem entender completamente o assunto.

Bom, estas foram algumas das considerações que faço pra votar positivo, se for lembrando de outras farei update aqui. Negativo mesmo eu só voto quando o usuário é estúpido, grosseiro. Até hoje foram só dois votos negativos.

Se alguém achar que estou votando errado, por favor, não se acanhe de me dizer.

Bom, espero que não tenha falado <s>nenhuma</s> muita bobagem, que não tenha ofendido ninguém, e que minhas observações acrescentem algo de útil ao debate.

Vida longa e próspera ao SOpt. :-)

Comment: Ótima resposta +1, sobre a escala de de 1 a 5, tem livro bacana sobre o assunto se tiver interesse [Building Web Reputation Systems](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596159801.do). Ainda não tem tradução para o português.

Comment: Sim, você pegou bem o espírito do que eu queria dizer ;)

Comment: Valeu @rray. Infelizmente meu inglês não é bom suficiente pra ler um livro em inglês, no máximo posts do Soen com a ajuda do google translate rsrs. Abraço!

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: *se um usuário de alta reputação respondeu, então a pergunta é boa* – não necessariamente, veja o que o Cigano disse sobre isso. Várias merecem +0, geralmente -0 ;)

Comment: Sim @bfavaretto, já estava pensando nisso mesmo... acho que preciso reconsiderar esse ponto... Valeu.

Comment: Não sei se a quantidade de pontos por usuário é relevante - seja como for contabilizada. A mim parece que o que importa é a quantidade de votos por pergunta, e se esse número for baixo, se é baixo devido à qualidade da pergunta ou à carência de votos...

Comment: Mas mais a propósito, sua resposta apresenta vários pontos que eu queria ver aqui, especialmente sobre razões para votar

Answer (score 7):

Eu fiz duas analises no SEDE, espero que as queries estejam corretas.

Primeiro, quis olhar o tempo médio entre as perguntas e as respostas finais (aceitas):

**[Média do tempo entre criação da pergunta e da resposta aceita](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/339637/average-of-time-between-posts-and-accepted-answer-creation-by-months).**

Não conto aqui as perguntas sem respostas. Acho que não fariam parte da análise nem que eu conseguisse incluí-las na query.

Em seguida, o tempo médio entre a criação da pergunta e o primeiro voto:

**[Média do tempo entre a criação da pergunta e do primeiro voto](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/339647/average-time-between-post-creation-and-first-vote).**

Não contando aqui as respostas que não tiveram nenhum voto.

---

O que notamos:

- O tempo entre o primeiro voto e a criação da pergunta gira em torno de 4 a 10 dias, com um mínimo de 2.
- O tempo entre a criação de uma pergunta e a criação da resposta aceita fica entre 1,5 e 3,5.

Também notamos que meus dados não são lá essas coisas, porque os valores mais antigos tem valores máximos muito mais altos. Pelo que entendo isso significa que esses gráficos vão ter a parte da esquerda mais alta por causa de outliers.

Mas acho que ainda servem se a gente não considerar a tendência, só os valores.

Enfim, o tempo médio entre pergunta e primeiro voto sempre é maior que o tempo médio entre pergunta e resposta aceita.

Isso significa que a pergunta média não é votada antes de ser respondida. Isso sem considerar as que nunca tiveram voto.

Claro que a votação após a resposta ainda é válida. Mas eu me pergunto o efeito disso na qualidade das respostas.

Comment: Mais tarde vou tentar limitar a distância para eliminar outliers das perguntas mais antigas.

Comment: Descobri que o horário dos votos no data explorer é sempre 00:00:00. Isso está comprometendo a sua segunda query. Mesmo assim, essas médias altas me assustaram.

Comment: Eu vi isso nas planilhas... quando coloquei em horas, obtive valores negativos :).

Comment: Os negativos só podem estar distorcendo o resultado. Hipoteticamente, se todas as perguntas fossem feitas às 23:59:59 UTC e votadas instantaneamente, com os votos registrados sempre como 0:00, a query daria 1 dia entre a postagem e o voto, quando na verdade seria 0 (em segundos).

Comment: Certo, mas o delta é no máximo um dia. E não temos como corrigir isso (já que os comentários são registrados sempre à meia noite)... Além disso, os outliers nas perguntas mais antigas poluem bem mais os resultados que isso.