# Como aumentar a quantidade de votos, com qualidade

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade

Na pergunta [Estamos com problemas? (quantidade de votos)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4166/26643), estabelecemos que existe um problema relativo à pouca quantidade de votos: a maioria se manifestou a favor, ou argumentou que algo deve ser feito.

Era minha intenção confirmar e estabelecer a condição de que a situação merece atenção.

### Antes de tudo

Eu queria dizer que acho isso uma situação natural. Após uma certa massa crítica (que é facilmente atingida pelo peso da rede SE), a razão entre contribuidores e usuários (espero que os nomes façam sentido) diminui. A quantidade de usuários cresce exponencialmente, enquanto com certeza a quantidade de contribuidores assíduos cresce, no máximo, linearmente.

Dito isso, acho ainda sim que essa tendência deve ser contrabalanceada. O conceito mais central, ao meu ver, é a necessidade de que as perguntas sejam avaliadas. A motivação para discutir isso veio, inclusive, do fato de ter notado que muitas perguntas não recebem votos.

Mais tarde, uma análise mostrou que o tempo médio para uma pergunta ser respondida é maior que o tempo médio para uma pergunta receber o primeiro voto. Ao meu ver, isso exige ação, ou pelo menos uma avaliação das opções.

### Soluções

Muitas pessoas emitiram opiniões sobre o que poderia ser feito, muitas também sobre o que não deveria.

Queria reunir aqui as ideias de como atacar isso.

Se me permitem dar palpite sobre as respostas, acho melhor uma 'ideia' por resposta, para que possa ser comentada/votada individualmente.

Comment: Só um detalhe. Não espere que a SE vá mudar o sistema de votação. Para o bem ou para o mal, ela não vai mudar. Primeiro porque não há muito o que fazer neste sentido. Mesmo que alguém ache uma solução excelente, não não andam muito propensos a mudar. Seja porque o software já está caindo aos pedaços, seja porque não precisa mexer em time que está ganhando. A gente não sabe exatamente o motivo mas eles raramente estão mexendo na mecânica do site. Se é que mexeram alguma coisa nos últimos 5 anos. Mesmo antes não mexeram em nada tão radicalmente.

Comment: Ah sim. Também acho improvável. Mas pretendo discutir as ideias. Mesmo sabendo que pouca coisa pode mudar, ainda assim acho que devemos tentar encontrar o que achamos que seria a solução. Aí sim provavelmente veremos que não poderá ser realizado. E quem sabe achamos um jeito que não precise de tanta alteração.

Answer (score 4):

**Separar critérios de votos**

Categoria: sistema de votos

---

Em inúmeros lugares, vemos membros mais antigos explicando que estratégia usam para votar. Em todos (os que vi), são explicadas várias razões para votar.

Com relação à votos negativos, acho que tudo está bem. A comunidade é sólida, e os números são bons.
A pergunta não está clara, é muito abrangente, mal formatada, não há indícios de pesquisa, etc. No final das contas, se a pergunta não pode ser respondida em sua forma atual, leva voto negativo, e geralmente é consistente.

Agora para votos up: boa formatação, o assunto é útil (para mim), a pergunta foi bem redigida, etc.

Mas quantos crítérios são necessários? E se eu tive, tenho, ou imagino ter uma dúvida, mas não sei se a pergunta está correta, ou mesmo se não foi respondida antes?

Eu acho que muita gente não vota pois não se sente a vontade para afirmar: essa pergunta está boa. Acho que um conceito que reforça isso é que muitos usuários não sabem fazer uma boa pergunta. Como, então, esperar que saibam reconhecer uma?

Assim, enfim, o que proponho aqui é separar os conceitos que consideramos 'votáveis':
A pergunta

- A pergunta é útil (em imagino que mais pessoas possam ter esse problema).
- A pergunta está bem redigida, pesquisada. Eu não acho que eu poderia perguntar de forma melhor.
- A pergunta está clara, direta.

(os critérios teriam que ser discutidos, a ideia geral é a que conta aqui)

Separando os critérios, seria possível também votar de forma independente: "sua pergunta é importante, mas está mal formulada" é uma frase que não temos como refletir no sistema atual, e que acho que incentiva tanto a persistir na pergunta quanto a melhorá-la. A versão atual é não votar, que não incentiva nada.

Comment: +1 Acho que seria legal divulgar uma lista de bons motivos pra votar em perguntas.

Comment: Não acho que exista uma oficial, nem haverá... é um tanto subjetivo, a ponto de ninguém querer 'impor' nem determinar uma filosofia oficial. Acho que seria interessante, se essa ideia for bem votada, discutir a fundo os critérios. Eu vejo uma interface com o botão de voto como está, mas logo abaixo um área com opções mais detalhadas: A pergunta está bem/mal formulada, a pergunta é frequente/rara, foi bem/mal pesquisada, etc...

Comment: Gostei da ideia das opções abaixo... Eu imagino que o ideal, ao invés dos botões como são, era ter ali um range 0-10 (ou como sugeri na resposta no outro tópico), mas acho que isso seria bem complicado, então a ideia de uma área abaixo, com mais opções, parece mais factível, embora não acredite que possa haver uma mudança nisso. Acho impossível mudarem um detalhe importante destes da interface.

Answer (score 3):

## Incentivar as pessoas a votarem

Acho que a solução sempre passa por aqui. Tentar criar o hábito nos utilizadores com mais reputação de votarem em tudo que é bom e não só onde lhes interessa. As vezes a mim acontece-me de ver uma boa resposta e eu ter respondido também e não voto. Mas a consciência pesa-me mais que ficar com mais um voto que o outro utilizador, acabo sempre por voltar a pergunta e votar.

Eu tenho visto é outro problema, perguntas muito fracas que mesmo com edições e pedidos de informações aos utilizadores dificilmente conseguem votos positivos. também não costumam ter negativos porque a pergunta não tão fraca assim que mereça o -1.

Também me acontece muito de levar com -1 só porque dei -1 noutra resposta e explico esse -1, acabo por levar um -1 muitas vezes injusto. **Mas isso não é o que me vai deixar de votar**.

Atualmente no [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/) sou o utilizador com [mais votos dados](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) e o [segundo com maior reputação](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) por isso como podem ver não vai afetar na vossa reputação o votarem muito. O que afeta a vossa reputação é darem boas respostas e boas perguntas. Muitos utilizadores se perceberem isso vão votar muito mais.

Comment: "O que afeta a vossa reputação é darem boas respostas e boas perguntas." +1

Comment: Acho que os votos negativos deveriam ser obrigatoriamente justificados, muita vezes se leva -1 e não se sabe o porque. Votos negativos sendo justificados ajudam a tornar as respostas melhores. pois se você sabe porque leva negativo, sabe onde melhorar.

Comment: @MeuChapeu se fosse obrigatório ninguém votava -1 e não saberíamos o que a comunidade acha mau

Answer (score 0):

**Mudar cultura de votos**

Categoria: cultura

---

Muitos dos argumentos que apareceram aqui e na pergunta anterior remetem à qualidade dos votos. Houve quem opinasse que não há poucos votos, há perguntas com qualidade que **merecem** poucos votos. Houve também muita gente que considera os dois fatores como reais e problemáticos.

Eu acho que os dois pontos (poucos votos e poucos mérito das perguntas) são o mesmo problema. Ausência de voto faz com que uma pergunta média não de destaque de uma ruim, e ambas de uma pergunta quase boa.

Talvez muitos dos que contribuem estejam acostumados com o nível de perguntas do SOen... talvez não. Mas eu disse antes: **votar em função do nível que queremos** fará com que as perguntas estagnem, ou nós fiquemos sem avaliar as perguntas. Nós temos que votar para **diferenciar as perguntas que temos, agora**.

Mas a questão pra mim é que se não distinguirmos as perguntas, elas não vão melhorar. Para perguntas de até 5 dias, **média de votos é menor que um**, a **moda é zero**. Como alguém que não conhece nada pode saber se sua pergunta é **boa, média ou ruim**, e porque?

Talvez nenhuma dessas perguntas realmente mereça votos. Mas **essa é a nossa realidade**. **Essas são nossas perguntas**. Se não votarmos nas perguntas "0,5", "0,8", como vamos saber que são melhores que as perguntas "0,1"?

Uma ideia seria votos graduais... de 1 a 5, como foi mencionado antes. Talvez uma separação dos critérios, para que alguém possa votar positivamente na utilidade da pergunta, mas negativamente na qualidade.

Enfim, o que eu acho é que precisamos fazer com que, de alguma forma, essas perguntas recebam votos. Só assim melhorarão.

Comment: Estou tentando arrumar tempo para responder a outra pergunta. Ter poucos votos e a qualidade das perguntas ser ruim são coisas distintas, é fácil comprovar. Primeiro porque qualidade ruim também merece voto... negativo, e estes faltam ainda mais. Segundo porque falta nas respostas, e embora algumas faltam qualidade, tem muito com qualidade, bem mais do perguntas. Quem responde costuma saber como fazer, ao contrário de quem pergunta. Existe um outro problema para as pessoas não votarem e espero abordar lá. Um problema é óbvio, é o novato não saber fazer ou não se preocupar com isto. Tem outro.

Comment: Não concordo com a ideia e nem com o @bigown. Temos perguntas que não têm problemas sérios, são +/- por isso nem dou voto + nem -. Uma pergunta que tem 0 votos quer dizer isso mesmo que é mais ou menos. RSinohara eu acho que, como eu disse na minha resposta, é incentivar as pessoas a fazerem boas perguntas. Tentar ensinar a perguntar com qualidade. Mas mesmo assim eu vejo aqui muitos problemas com as perguntas: *"não me apetece debugar, debuguem por mim"*.

Comment: Ah e @bigown muitas vezes numa pergunta +/- surgem respostas +/. porque a pergunta não está clara, mas as pessoas preferem tentar responder e tentar ganhar +1 do que fechar a pergunta e pedir esclarecimentos. Tem muita resposta boa, mas que não consigo perceber se responde a pergunta, por causa da pergunta. Então não dou nem + nem -.

Comment: Olha eu concordo em parte contigo @JorgeB. Mas eu acho que bigown disse é certo também, veja esta pergunta e resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47418/3635 lhe parecem *ruim* ou  *+ou-*? Se sim, então realmente eu vejo muitas perguntas com pontuação "astronômicas" que são +ou-. Se não então por que a resposta tem tão poucos votos? Foi a maneira que foi escrita? Eu pessoalmente não sei. Pra mim o que o bigown disse é certo também, *poucos votos e a qualidade das perguntas ser ruim são coisas distintas*. Não estou discordando, só acho que cada caso é um caso apenas isto :)

Comment: Eu concordo que são distintas, mas acho que os votos são a melhor forma de _discernir_ entre as de má qualidade, as médias e as boas, e isso leva a melhorar as médias e talvez as ruins. São coisas diferentes, mas há uma relação de causa e efeito.

Answer (score -3):

**Exibir peso dos votos**

Categoria: sistema de votos, incentivo aos primeiros votos, 'recompensar' votos

---

Um item que acho curioso: Uma pergunta com 7 votos é boa?

E se eu disser que a pergunta tem 30 votos a favor, 23 contra?

A contagem de votos não mostra a divisão, só o *grand-total*. Isso não é de todo mal, mas que tal duas perguntas, ambas com 3 votos, uma 7/-4 e uma 3/0? Acho que há uma diferença. Acho que essa diferença impacta sobretudo no começo.

A ideia? Somente na página inicial, alterar a contagem de votos com um fator, digamos +5 para unanimidade, +3 para maioria (>75%), +2 para maioria simples. Os valores poderiam ser proporcionais ao total, talvez.

Para que serve? Dar um up, especialmente, para votações unânimes, mas também (talvez mais importante), incentivar os primeiros votos: os dois primeiros votos valem muito.

Comment: -1 tbm Acho que seria melhor se fosse possível, de alguma forma, saber estes valores (os votos positivos e negativos). Não é, né?

Comment: @gustavox Um usuário com 1000 ou mais pontos pode [visualizar a contagem dos votos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Comment: Legal, valeu @ramaral!

Comment: @gustavox Ver esses valores já seria bem útil...

Comment: Eu sou a favor de reduzir a pontuação exigida para ver os votos +/- separadamente, mas não acho que isso incentive as pessoas a votar mais.

Comment: @bfavaretto Também não. A ideia aqui era mais fazer com que as pessoas sentissem que os primeiros votos valem muito, pois impactam o resultado mais, sem afetar o resultado final. Talvez ver a quantidade de votos + e - seja um bom critério para avaliar a pergunta, mas não para incentivar os votos.

Answer (score -5):

**Valorizar primeiros votos**

Categoria: sistema de votos, incentivo aos primeiros votos, recompensar votos

---

Nunca fiz, mas aposto que se traçarmos uma tendência dos votos após o 5º voto, a tendência é seguida. Ou seja, após os 5 primeiros votos, estes só serão reforçados. Acho que os primeiros votos são primordiais.

Eu sei que recompensar votos é complicado. Mas eu disse antes: a recompensa pode ser vista como uma indicação clara de que um comportamento é recomendado.

A ideia aqui é recompensar, no máximo 1 ou 2 vezes por dia/semana, os 2 ou 3 primeiros votos para as perguntas que eventualmente atingirem 10 votos (números a rever). Além disso, talvez aumente o comprometimento dos votantes para que a pergunta seja melhorada.

A mensagem é clara, e foi dita antes: [Vote early, vote often](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Comment: -1 Não achei a ideia boa, ia recompensar como, com pontos de rep?

Comment: Sim, a ideia é com pontos... eu sei que é uma forma bem controversa... sinceramente espero que a gente ache um jeito diferente, mas também acho essa possibilidade válida, digna de ser discutida.

Comment: Meu ponto não é 'pagar' pelos votos... mas a recompensa deixa claro que uma atitude é incentivada: ninguém edita posts para conseguir rep... é muito lento. Mas os 2 pontos servem como uma indicação clara que a atitude é desejada. Quando falo em recompensa, penso que seja em uma quantidade pequena demais para afetar a 'economia', mas que deixe claro: queremos que votem. Os primeiros votos mais ainda.

Comment: Com certeza é digno de discussão, mas imho existem formas melhores (como a primeira que você postou) pra incentivar o voto em perguntas. Os próprios tópicos que você criou acho que já estão mudando a forma de pensar de alguns users... Enfim, acho que recompensar voto com rep não é uma boa. Mas é só a minha opinião, respeito a sua, é uma ideia...

Comment: Eu mesmo acho que mexer na economia é ultimo caso e extremamente complicado... e provavelmente fadado a dar errado... afinal, esse é o centro das muitas comunidades do SE, e acho que pra fazer diferente tem que ter muito cacife... Dito isso, também acho que esse problema de votos acontece em muitas comunidades, e talvez uma solução aqui pode ser útil em outros.