# Poucos votos positivos em perguntas

Tags: debate

Ultimamente tenho reparado que muitas das perguntas novas ou ficam com 0 pontos ou recebem pontos negativos. Sendo que quando verifiquei de **45 perguntas, 14 tinham pontuação negativa, 3 pontuação positiva e as restantes neutras**.

Muita das vez as perguntas com pontuação negativa receberam por estarem mal estruturadas e as pessoas que votam negativamente deixam um comentário para o que as pessoas tem de corrigirem. Os usuários muitas das vezes corrigem mas as pessoas que deixaram o voto negativo não o removem porque não voltam a verificar a pergunta mais, deixando depois uma pergunta bem estruturada e corrigida com pontuação negativa e recebe menos atenção de outros.

Na minha opinião os usuários tem muito mais tendência a votarem negativamente que positivamente o que leva para um rácio de muitas perguntas negativas. E também dão mais importância a votar nas respostas que na pergunta em si.

**Minhas questão:**

Será que são os usuários não estão habituados a votarem positivamente nas perguntas, não se deve votar positivamente em perguntas bem estruturadas e pertinentes para dar atenção a elas?

E será que as pessoas que votam negativamente não tem interesse a verificar se a pergunta fico bem reestruturada nunca mais alterando o seu voto?

Comment: Muitas perguntas são só erros bobos, uma simples pesquisa aqui no SOpt mesmo já resolveria, não são duplicatas, mas pode se chegar a solução por elas, também tem a documentação. Pessoalmente não voto nessas, nem a favor nem contra

Comment: Eu não acho que as pessoas têm mais tendência para votar negativo. O que eu acho é: [por ter muito mais perguntas ruins do que boas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/112052), acabamos vendo mais votos negativos do que positivos. Se a maioria das perguntas fossem boas, veríamos o contrário, então os votos só refletem o que está sendo postado. Na verdade, acho até que tem muita pergunta ruim que mesmo assim recebe votos positivos (bem mais do que perguntas boas que eventualmente levam um negativo, aliás).

Comment: Quando fiz a contagem não contabilizei com perguntas [Fechadas], [Duplicadas], etc...

Comment: Apenas para fixar ali na lateral: [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/5878) / [Estamos com problemas? (falta de votos)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4166/5878) / [Como aumentar a quantidade de votos, com qualidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4190/5878) / [Eu não sei perguntar, e você?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4829/5878) / [O que está acontecendo com os votos negativos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4800/5878) / [Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/5878)

Comment: Quanto a reavaliar os votos depois que a pergunta é melhorada, *mea culpa*: de fato poderia ser feito com mais frequência. Mas minha experiência é que a grande maioria nunca melhora de fato (na maioria das vezes os comentários dizendo para melhorar são ignorados, ou a pessoa até edita mas não melhora nada). Daí, como eu "já sei" que a maioria nunca melhora a pergunta, acabo não conferindo com frequência se algo foi melhorado, e os poucos casos em que são, acabam passando despercebidos...

Comment: "*não contabilizei com perguntas [Fechadas]*" - esse já é outro problema: existem mais perguntas a serem fechadas do que pessoas para fazê-lo. Cada um tem um limite de votos de fechamento por dia (acho que 24), só usuários com pontuação >= 3000 podem votar para fechar (não há tantos ativos atualmente) e precisa de 5 votos (moderadores [não tem esse limite diário](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183761/401803), mas eles também são humanos e não passam 24 horas por dia no site). Enfim, tem muita coisa ruim que deveria ser fechada mas não foi...

Comment: Eu já vi resposta completamente errada com mais de 30 positivos e só o meu negativo. Mesmo eu mostrando para usuários experientes não quiseram negativar porque ficaram na dúvida se estava errada depois de tantos positivos, por isso os votos ajudam, mas também prejudicam.

Answer (score 11):

> Será que são os usuários não estão habituados a votarem positivamente nas perguntas, não se deve votar positivamente em perguntas bem estruturadas e pertinentes para dar atenção a elas?

Sim. Minha experiência é que poucas perguntas são boas. Eu tenho positivado poucas perguntas ultimamente, isso era diferente no passado. A qualidade caiu muito. A maioria das perguntas inclusive deveriam ser fechadas (eu estava fazendo bastante mas resolvi diminuir o ritmo porque é enxugar gelo).

A maioria das perguntas atuais não estão claras, e boa parte delas apenas expõe um desejo do que querem fazer e esperam que as pessoas façam para elas. Infelizmente algumas pessoas são voluntariosas e tentam responder mesmo assim, em muitos casos causando mais estrago porque a pergunta é ambíguo ou cheia de furos e passar ser mais a opinião dela sobre o que é a pergunta. Em geral essas respostas mal ajuda a pessoa, mesmo a pessoa aceitando a resposta (grande parte das aceitações ocorre por agradecimento e não porque a solução é boa), e é quase certo que não ajuda outras pessoas que sempre foi o objeto do site (o objetivo nunca foi ajudar só a pessoa e isso por si só deveria ser usado para avaliar se a pergunta é boa).

É claro que cada um pode votar como quiser, mas para a comunidade fluir melhor seria bom só votar em perguntas que ajudam várias pessoas e destacar esse conteúdo. Eu vejo hoje a esmagadora maioria das perguntas como pedidos de ajuda para um problema que só ajuda a pessoa.

Na verdade eu vejo muito mais positivo onde não deve  do que negativo onde não é tão ruim. Algumas pessoas tem um critério bem baixo do que é uma pergunta bem feita e na minha opinião isso é mais prejudicial à qualidade do site.

> E será que as pessoas que votam negativamente não tem interesse a verificar se a pergunta fico bem reestruturada nunca mais alterando o seu voto?

Em geral as pessoas não voltam para ver, já foi sugerido ter alguma notificação disso, mas nunca tivemos sucesso, ou até resposta sobre o assunto. Há alguns anos uma pessoa supostamente especialista em UX foi contratada para melhorar esse aspecto e poderia ver se isso é interessante ou não e dar um parecer definitivo, mas nunca vimos nada sobre o assunto ou mesmo conseguimos ver claramente algum trabalho de UX, muda-se o *layout* do site aqui ou ali, mas o grosso dos problemas permanecem e as pessoas vão se adaptando a isso, uma dessas formas e abandonar o que já foi revisado uma vez.

Minha experiência é que raramente a pergunta é melhorada, em geral o usuário não tem condições de fazer isso, falta entendimento do problema, o básico de programação, não consegue se expressar (não entende comunicação expressão nem para o básico e conceitos mínimos de matemática e método científico). Em geral ele não quer fazer os que as pessoas indicam pra ele, não lê os *links* do site que ajudam a se dar melhor, e pra ser bem franco eles não estão tão interessados assim na solução, claro que querem seu problema resolvido, mas magicamente, não querem se comprometer com isso, assumem é responsabilidade dos outros ajudá-lo de toda forma possível e ele não precisa fazer nada, caprichar, etc. Estas pessoas vão sempre se frustrar, na vida, não só aqui. Em geral porque os pais não queriam ser os frustadores deles, como todo pai deveria ser, mas que hoje muito não o são por enorme carência. É muito comum essas pessoas começarem atacar as pessoas que poderiam ajudá-los. Eles consideram-se [floquinhos de neve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_(slang)) e não valorizam o esforço que estão fazendo gratuitamente para ajudá-los. Claro que nem todas perguntas ruins seja por isso.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50942/como-adicionar-uma-rolagem-horizontal-no-css, para mim não faz sentido uma questão com 12mil visualizações ter menos de 5 pontos isso é  menos de >0.05% de votos. As visualizações contam só para pessoas que deram login ou qualquer pessoa que veja a pergunta?

Comment: @Pbras Acessos de usuários não-logados [também contam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/401803). E já vi uma palestra de uma pessoa que trabalha no Stack Overflow e foi dito que a grande maioria dos acessos é de usuários não-logados.

Comment: Pra mim faz todo sentido, popularidade nada tem a ver com qualidade e  os votos que deveriam indicar isso. A pergunta é ruim, é só uma "como faz isso?" que hoje seria fechada porque não há dúvida real. As visualizações contam pra todo mundo, inclusive as que acharam que a pergunta era ruim e as respostas não servem para ela ou talvez nem para o AP, mas ele nem sabe disto porque ele não tem conhecimento para avaliar se aquilo é bom.

Comment: @hkotsubo Mas isso já seria de esperar. Eu diria que o grosso dos acessos vem de pessoal que pesquisa no google e que não é assíduo no SO e por isso não tem conta/não estão logados.