# Usuários que pedem voto, seria ético?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, votos

Vejo em algumas perguntas, pessoas pedindo votos a favor de sua reposta, isso seria certo? Entendo que em alguns casos quem pergunta é novo na comunidade e nunca mais vai logar no site para avaliar a resposta. O que vocês acham dessa prática, levando em consideração que esses comentários ficam nas perguntas, local onde é destinado para tirar dúvidas sobre a pergunta (se não estou enganado)?

Sou novo aqui no SOPT e estou tentando entender toda sua filosofia para poder contribuir com a comunidade.

Comment: tenho quase a certeza que já foi discutido isso aqui, mas não encontro onde...

Comment: Também procurei, se já foi discutido queria o link para ver o debate, caso exista, apago essa pergunta.

Comment: Relacionado: [Devemos pedir para aceitar resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1425/3117)

Comment: Acho que foi debatido sobre aceitação. Depende muito de como é feito. Teria que ver cada caso. Se for feita em forma de orientação, imparcial, não tem problema. Eu acho que pedir votos é muito bom, pedir para si, principalmente se for em detrimento de outros se torna um problema. E é, na perguntas postada no comentário do Math tem alguns critérios que acho que valem p/ voto também.

Answer (score 18):

Ainda sou a favor da campanha [Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2161/5818) Desde que não seja na propria pergunta ou resposta, acho que temos que incentivar o voto, mas sem "mendigar" o mesmo.

Comment: Eu fazia isto no Programmers. Eu s[o não estou fazendo aqui porque tem gente que vai dizer que eu estou querendo chamar atenção para o mesmo *post* no meta (que nem é de minha autoria de fato). Eu acho que deveria alertar as pessoas para votar mais. Tem muita gente votando pouco. Tem usuários que não votam porque não entendem bem o processo e importância, muitas vezes ão usuários que são enormemente ajudados no *site* e no máximo votam quem respostas nas suas perguntas. Tem usuários que não votam porque assim eles podem ficar mais bem posicionados entre os usuários.

Comment: kkk uma resposta de 2 linhas com 8 "likes" rsrsr

Comment: kkk @DanielOmine, mais um like só pelo deboche, faça uma boa resposta então.

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza, foi apenas uma ironia devido a alguns aqui que fecham ou negativam respostas de 1 linha, por exemplo. Muitas vezes sem necessidade ou apenas por retaliação.

Answer (score 8):

Acho que depende do caso e depende da forma como é feito. E há duas coisas distintas aqui que embora semelhantes, é importante diferenciar: Pedir votos a favor é uma coisa, pedir para aceitar a resposta é outra coisa.

Por exemplo, é comum onde você posta uma reposta, e depois o autor da pergunta vem e posta um comentário "*Valeu, obrigado, funcionou direitinho*", mas a sua resposta não é aceita e nem recebe voto a favor. Neste caso, acho válido pedir para o autor da pergunta aceitá-la.

Ou então, você vai em alguma pergunta que tem aquela solução "mais-ou-menos, meia boca" com uns 5 votos a favor e daí você posta uma solução completa e elegante e... aparentemente ninguém percebe, mas a resposta antiga continua a receber votos a favor. Neste caso, vale a pena perguntar o que está acontecendo.

Por outro lado, se o autor da pergunta (ou alguma outra pessoa) reclamou de várias coisas que ele considera problemáticas ou insatisfatórias na sua resposta, pedir voto a favor ou pedir a aceitação é claramente inadequado.

Também é inadequado pedir votos a favor se a sua resposta não for significativamente melhor que as demais respostas existentes.

E a forma utilizada para pedir votos a favor ou pedir a aceitação é importante. O tom utilizado no texto deve ser sempre sugestivo e nunca impositivo. E você deve ser sempre humilde e educado. Por exemplo, isso daqui normalmente é bom:

> @Fulano, já que a minha resposta te ajudou a solucionar o seu problema, então se você não tiver mais nenhuma dúvida, poderia por favor aceitá-la? Caso ainda haja alguma dúvida ou algum ponto a esclarecer, me diga por favor para que possamos esclarecê-la.

Já isso daqui é ruim:

> @Fulano, vi que você ainda não votou a favor da minha resposta. Você deve votar a favor dela e aceitá-la.

Isso daqui é pior ainda:

> @Fulano, ei, ao invés de ficar perdendo tempo conversando com o Cliclano na resposta inútil dele, vai logo na minha resposta e dê o voto a favor e a aceitação, pois a minha resposta é a melhor que você vai encontrar.

E para completar, isso que descrevo acima se aplica só para o caso de pedir voto ou aceitação para o autor da pergunta em uma resposta da mesma pergunta. Se o caso for pedir voto para outros usuários, ou pedir voto em respostas de outras perguntas, ou pedir votos em perguntas, então ou muito raramente ou nunca tal comportamento seria adequado.

Answer (score 6):

Eu acredito que o problema não seja ético mas a credibilidade da resposta de uma pessoa que pede o voto decai bastante. Todavia não chega a ser um problema até porque o pedido de voto do usuário que respondeu não vai influenciar a qualidade da resposta dele. Então se realmente for boa, que seja votada a favor, caso não, seu pedido de voto não valerá nada no fim das contas.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que mendigar voto é que nem mendigar like em instagram. 
É ridiculo, esquisito, a pessoa perde a credibilidade e me dá muita vergonha alheia. 
Votos, assim como curtidas, têm que ser porque você achou necessário e não porque a pessoa pediu.

Comment: Algumas pessoas não entendem como o sistema funcionam. Por exemplo, se você tem pontuação o suficiente para dar um voto (up ou down) e também tem o conhecimento técnico para discernir se a reposta é útil ou não, então deveria dar o voto. Vejo muita gente (usuário ocasional) que posta a dúvida, obtém sinais de que a pergunta foi positiva para aprofundar o conhecimento (através de up-votes na questão) e respostas boas (inclusive que resolvem seu problema), comentam um simples "obrigado, deu certo" e abandonam a questão pra sempre

Comment: Os votos (e a aceitação) indicam para um visitante qual conteúdo já passou pela curadoria da comunidade, do AP e o que é, de modo geral, mais valioso. Inclusive, isso ajuda no [filtro de bom conteúdo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7198/porque-existe-tanta-restri%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-sopt-em-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ao-soen#comment30965_8016), necessário a todo agregador de conhecimento indexável de modo wiki