# Vamos fazer uma campanha para incentivar as pessoas a votarem?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Faz um tempo que discutimos sobre como incentivar os novos e até mesmo antigos usuários do SO-pt a votarem mais. Porém esse discução se prolonga cada vez mais e não se chega a decisão nenhuma.

**Minha proposta é a seguinte:**

1. Respondam esse post com propostas de campanhas
2. Votem nesse post para definir se vamos ou não fazer a campanha
3. Ajudem a determinar um data limite para encerrarmos a votação e iniciarmos ou não a campanha.
4. A resposta mais votada sera usada como campanha.

**Links relacionados.**

1. [Usuários que pedem voto, seria ético?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2498/usu%C3%A1rios-que-pedem-voto-seria-%C3%A9tico)
2. [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)
3. [Devemos pedir para aceitar resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425/devemos-pedir-para-aceitar-resposta)
4. [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

**Pontos que gostaria de chamar a atenção**

> **Encerrado no dia 2 de Abril. O tópico permanece aberto para o debate**

Comment: Acredito que pegar o resultado no dia 2 de Abril seria bom para dar tempo suficiente para pensarmos bem sobre isso e decidirmos da melhor forma o que vamos fazer

Comment: Excelente iniciativa :)

Comment: Eu até acho que incentivar é legal, mas tenho medo de interpretarem como "vote em qualquer coisa". Eu sempre voto no que eu realmente acho de "qualidade" e em assuntos que eu entendo, se for alguma linguagem que eu não domino de maneira avançada, por melhor que a resposta soe, eu não vejo motivo para votar, pois não posso afirmar nada. Mas mesmo assim achei boa a sua campanha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acredito que uma resposta não precise ser excelente para merecer votos, se responde a pergunta do autor de forma clara já é suficiente para merecer votos, até por que o que se vê hoje no site é que o numero de votos cresce de acordo com o número de linhas que tem a resposta...

Comment: Concordo com este último aspeto que o Rodrigo referenciou...

Comment: Sobre o último parágrafo acho que não seja o número de linhas, mas sim o número de edições. Só acho (: concordo com a campanha, mas é incentivar dentro do seu conhecimento mínimo do assunto da postagem

Comment: Gostaria de saber a opinião do @Gabe quanto a isso

Comment: Você imaginou algo como um banner na lateral do site, é isso? Isso o Gabe precisaria ver com a equipe dele se é possível. Se não for, o que temos à disposição são meta-posts em destaque, e comentários.

Comment: @bfavaretto o que o `Orion` disse que já viu no site gringo uma mensagem no topo da página, que segundo ele quer dizer resumidamente "se gostou vote". pensei em fazer algo assim, pode ser um banner lateral ou no topo, seria melhor que usar os comentarios, pois poderia ser facilmente removido depois, diferente dos comentarios que provavelmente não serão excluidos, pelo menos não todos eles...

Comment: Estamos nos aproximando do fim do período estipulado.

Comment: Seria interessante uma fila de análise com tamanho indefinido, no qual o usuário vai votando em todas as perguntas do site. É possível fazer isso manualmente, indo de pergunta a pergunta, mas essa fila facilitaria o processo.

Comment: @Patrick Todas as pergunta do site acho exagero. Mas uma fila de perguntas e respostas sem votos (ou com poucos votos), e que já esfriaram (sem atividade há X dias) poderia ser uma boa solução para o problema. Não quer propor isso? Pode usar minha ideia se quiser.

Comment: Fique à vontade para fazê-lo, não o colocaria da forma correta.

Answer (score 26):

## Vamos lá

Eu sou totalmente favorável. Sempre achei que o pessoal vota pouco, especialmente agora está rolando menos votos porque são poucas pessoas que se preocupam em classificar o conteúdo do *site* e por um motivo ou outro estas pessoas estão afastadas do *site*.

Acho que temos que incentivar pelo menos para o pessoal que ainda não entendeu a importância dos votos. Eu percebo que algumas pessoas usam o *site* como fórum, elas não entendem que elas podem aprender muito em ler, analisar e votar em perguntas que não são as suas. Se elas usassem o *site* como um Q&A provavelmente teriam menos perguntas para fazer e quando tenham serão perguntas mais úteis para todos.

## Alguns usuários não percebem que podem e devem votar em tudo que é útil para elas

Tem alguns usuários, e dá para perceber isto especialmente em usuário com alto número de perguntas, que eles deram menos votos que perguntas que fizeram.

## Há usuários que não votam por estratégia ou porque não se importam

Alguns usuários eu não sei se vão mudar muito, alguns usuários não votam porque isto vai dar reputação para outras pessoas e é a última coisa que elas desejam. Ninguém é obrigado a votar mas dá para perceber quem quer ajudar a comunidade e quem está preocupado com seus interesses.

Não é estranho que existam tantas pessoas capazes que ganhar a medalha de [**espírito esportivo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) e tão poucas ganharam? Aqui no Area 51 dá para acompanhar mais fácil a quantidade de perguntas que a pessoa fez. Em geral em boa parte delas a pessoa tem "concorrentes". Alguns usuários não tem problemas em votar em respostas boas que concorrem com a deles. Mas eu vejo que muitas pessoas evitam. Claro que não é para votar em qualquer coisa, nem todas respostas "concorrentes" são boas. Mas muitas vezes é. Com algumas pessoa você sabe que vai receber votos, outras você sabe que dificilmente vai receber, aí você tem que estrategicamente esperar para ver o que vai fazer com as respostas destas pessoas. Não é o ideal mas se você não faz isto você acaba prejudicado.

Outra coisa curiosa que dá para observar é que algumas pessoas receberam bem mais votos que deram; Veja o [*ranking* de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) e o [*ranking* de votantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all). Comparando caso a caso vemos casos com proporção de 1 dado para 2 recebidos. De novo, ninguém é obrigado a votar mas se a pessoa dedica tanto tempo ao *site* fica estranho que ela mal vote nas perguntas que responde, quanto mais em outras respostas.

## Usuários generosos

Por sorte algumas pessoas votaram dezenas de vezes mais do que receberam votos. Temos que agradecer a generosidade. SE a pessoa não consegue contribuir respondendo, pelo menos ajudam bastante votando.

## Não podemos incentivar o voto a esmo

É claro que qualquer indicação para usuário votarem precisa deixar claro para só votar no que eles sabem que ela pode considerar útil.

Não precisa ser uma resposta fenomenal para ser classificada como útil. Se achou uma utilidade para si próprio e acha que outras pessoas vão se beneficiar disto, se a pergunta é interessante e está bem feita ou se a resposta está respondendo razoavelmente bem a pergunta, porque não votar? Claro que pode existir um motivo.

Não podemos votar em respostas que não acrescentam nada, que passam informações erradas mesmo que uma parte esteja certa, ou respostas que não sigam as regras da comunidade. Embora o voto seja individual e cada um usa o critério que quiser, votar usando critério esdrúxulos não vai ajudar a comunidade e aí é até melhor que a pessoa não vote.

Precisamo encontrar o [comentário enlatado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/707/101) interessante que passe a informação da importância do voto e rapidamente indique que deve votar em todas as coisas úteis que encontrar evitando votar sem critério.

## Voto negativo

Como última informação importante, é preciso votar negativo também. Eu sei que algumas pessoas acham que isto prejudica pessoas. Mas se elas postaram algo que prejudicam a comunidade porque devemos ter essa preocupação? Os interesses da comunidade devem vir antes dos interesses individuais.

Eu sou quem mais vota negativo e quem mais vota positivo em todo o *site*. Mas o que poucas pessoas sabem que eu praticamente só voto negativo em perguntas e que a maioria do que eu voto, perguntas ou as poucas respostas, acaba sendo removido do *site* de tão ruim que era. Se a remoção do *post* removesse o voto negativo sobraria poucos votos negativos que teria dado. Grande parte dos votos negativos que dou ocorrem depois que passou um tempo e não deu para salvar a pergunta.

Eu sou favorável a salvar qualquer coisa que pareça salvável. Infelizmente eu não posso salvar tudo e se ninguém mais o faz (alguns gostam de discursar para os outros fazer mas raramente ajuda salvar alguma coisa) eu acho que algo ruim precisa ser classificado para baixo. Algumas vezes espero para dar voto positivo também, já vi vários casos que algo bom se transformou em algo ruim.

Vira e mexe eu reviso perguntas que assunto que me interessam para ver se falta votar em alguma coisa para cima ou para baixo. Raramente alguém ganha vários negativos meus, em geral eu negativo perguntas que são abandonadas pelo autor. O que eu às vezes tenho que tomar cuidado é para não dar serial *upvote* sem querer. Se sua pergunta abandonada recebeu um negativo depois de um tempo tem chance de ter sido eu. Se você recebeu alguns votos quase seriais, também pode ser por minha causa, principalmente se você costuma responder em assuntos que me interessam.

Comment: Eu sigo dois critérios para votar: 1) É algo que eu sei que é certo, bom e está bem explicado.  2) Algo que me acrescentou algum conhecimento... Acho que é a forma que tenho para agradecer ao _user_ por ter dedicado seu tempo em elaborar uma pergunta/resposta.

Answer (score 18):

Minha proposta continua a mesma de sempre:

Deixar a seguinte mensagem nos comentarios de perguntas e respostas.

> **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Comment: Colocava só um "Vote conscientemente!" ali depois do "Vote sempre!".

Comment: Ou então um rodapé: "Lembrando que o voto deve ser consciente e responsável: vote somente em conteúdo de alta qualidade. Voto negativo também conta!"

Comment: @JorgeB. `vote consciente!` não seria melhor?

Comment: A ideia do rodapé é boa também, mas acho que deixando no titulo da campanha chama mais a atenção

Comment: No site gringo eu já vi a mensagem que aparece no topo da página, resumidamente é "se gostou vote", aqui no sopt nunca vi.