# Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!

Tags: debate, voto-contra, votos, votação

Passado mais de um mês desde a criação do debate sobre fazer ou não uma campanha chegamos ao resultado.

**[Vamos fazer uma campanha para incentivar as pessoas a votarem?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2510/vamos-fazer-uma-campanha-para-incentivar-as-pessoas-a-votarem)**

Até o momento tivemos 28 votos a favor e nenhum voto contra.
Isso é bastante preocupante pois em várias discussões, várias pessoas contestavam bastante a ideia e algumas eram extremamente contra. Não vi nenhuma manifestação quanto a isso, nem uma contestação.

Porém, debate é debate, quem cala consente. Tivemos tempo suficiente para qualquer pessoa se manifestar, votar e dar sugestões.

A campanha selecionada foi:

> **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Código-fonte da campanha:

```
 **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)
```

A princípio, sugiro usarmos a campanha durante 30 dias e após esse período fazermos uma análise de resultados. Se com base nos resultados, deduzirmos que vale a pena continuar, vamos continuar. Caso contrário, vamos parar a campanha.

Vamos colocar o código-fonte nos comentários de perguntas com bastante visualizações e poucos votos principalmente. Também seria interessante colocarmos em perguntas de novatos.
Não vamos colocar em perguntas bem votadas para evitar a poluição do site. A ideia é fazer um arrastão futuramente para remover os comentários e deixar o site limpo novamente. Porém, até esse dia, os comentários vão permanecer para garantirmos que seja visualizada pelo maior número possível de usuários.

Como disse o @Maniero, "Vamos lá".

Comment: Código fonte pra colocar aonde???

Comment: @PapaCharlie Coloca nos comentários, vai ficar igual ao texto a cima do código fonte

Comment: Em qualquer questão ou só dos 'novatos'? Vitalício ou removível depois de um tempo? Confesso que não entendi o *onde*.

Comment: @PapaCharlie atualizado com uma explicação melhor

Comment: Eu não fui exatamente contra, eu só não entendi a abordagem e também falei que votos deveriam ser feitos dentro conhecimento, ou seja a formar de colocar "essa campanha" para os demais. Isto não é ser contra em minha opinião.

Comment: Se a comunidade fosse nossa (como dizem que é), poderia até existir um banner em algum lugar da página explicando isso ai. Como não é assim, acho que a ideia de colar a frase nos comentários é válida. Mas 30 dias não é muito tempo?

Comment: Ainda acho que colocar uma fila de análise para votos seria mais viável do que colocar comentários. Vejo uma deturpação da função do comentário nesta campanha.

Comment: @renan os 30 dais são pra termos um tempo melhor de comparação pros resultados

Comment: @Patrick concordo que a fila é uma excelente ideia, mas se as pessoas não votam assim, por que iriam ver a fila pra votar?

Comment: Porque facilita o trabalho.

Comment: @Patrick se 100 pessoas olham uma pergunta e nenhuma vota na pergunta, por elas iriam votar nas questões na fila? elas tiveram a oportunidade de votar e simplesmente não quiseram votar, então a fila acabaria sendo ignorada. Pelo menos é oque eu acho, se estão entrando nas perguntas lendo e não votando, eles não vao olhar a fila, ler e votar. o maximo seria eles entrarem e votarem sem ler, isso acabaria prejudicando a comunidade.

Comment: A diferença é que elas estariam lá apenas para votar, se não, não entrariam na fila.

Comment: @Patrick e essas pessoas seriam as mesmas que já votam hoje. A finalidade da campanha é atingir as pessaos que ainda não votam. A fila seria para, como voce disse, "facilitar o trabalho", mas não atingiria os usuários que ainda não votam.

Comment: Esse titulo pareceu propagando politica kkkk

Vote 1386 para RodrigoBorth como vereador

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha asuashuas pelo menos diga `Deputado Estadual`

Comment: @RodrigoBorth verdade verdade kk, pena que não posso mais editar :(

Comment: Não sei dizer se existe esse recurso no SOpt porque nunca aconteceu comigo, mas no SOen vez por outra recebo uma mensagem mais ou menos assim ao votar em respostas: "Você esteve votando somente em respostas durante algum tempo, perguntas também merecem votos". É um alerta legal para os usuários logados e visualização na pergunta não necessariamente serve como parâmetro, como pontuou o @PapaCharlie na resposta.

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 25):

Acho que muita gente vem ao SO somente pra resolver um ou outro problema pontual, outros podem não ter conhecimento além do próprio problema que vieram resolver ou têm um conhecimento muito raso para influenciar um voto, outros se abstém por não entenderem o funcionamento do SO, ou simplesmente não votam por egoísmo.

Se um usuário novo analisou uma questão e julgou que não há necessidade de voto e depois receber um comentário que `[...] seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade [...]`, pode acabar achando que votar `+1` ou `-1` é a regra, mas muitas questões simplesmente não merecem voto.

Acho que não é um problema para usuários finais resolverem. Embora tenhamos noção do que ocorre e possamos propor mudanças. Eu mesmo já propus algumas. Fazer os usuários entenderem a necessidade de votar e votarem com consciência, deve ser uma proposta da SO. *Acho a ideia válida*, mas creio que deva ser levado à *staff*, até mesmo como feedback de um *problema*.

<sub>Não estou desmotivando a ideia, estou fomentando o debate :)</sub>

Comment: Concordo, só complementando sobre os usuários novos: Eles nem possuem reputação suficiente para dar *upvote* ou *downvote* em alguma postagem. Logo, nada eles podem fazer por essa campanha.

Comment: Disse tudo, a abordagem do texto é que tornará claro e tem que ser analisado antes de aplicado, como eu disse, acho legal a campanha, mas se não tomar cuidado o pessoal vai votar em qualquer coisa: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2510/vamos-fazer-uma-campanha-para-incentivar-as-pessoas-a-votarem#comment8547_2510

Comment: Faz sentido o que você disse, mas acho que cabe a quem posta o comentário saber as situações a evitar. Usuários que aparecem no site uma vez e somem não são os melhores alvos, e sim quem já tem algumas perguntas postadas, mas poucos votos, ou até nenhum. Sempre verifiquem o perfil do usuário antes de deixar um comentários. Fora isso, não acho que o texto proposto incentive o voto "cego". Diz lá, em negrito: "vote consciente".

Comment: @bfavaretto, o SO-PT podia ter um BOT para encontrar exatamente esses usuários e disparar uma notificação quando estiverem logados. Algumas coisas podem evoluir e refinar o sistema.

Comment: É uma boa ideia, você pode postar uma pergunta aqui no meta com a tag [meta-tag:novo-recurso]. Concordo que a ferramenta pode e deve evoluir. É que entendo que a campanha proposta aqui seja um chamado de ação para a própria comunidade. Claro que a SE pode ajudar, e muito, mas nós também precisamos fazer a nossa parte.

Comment: @bfavaretto, depois abro uma questão sobre o recurso. Alguma proposta de novo recurso já foi adotada? Já vi algumas *propostas* mas não acompanhei o desfecho.

Comment: Sem querer te desanimar, geralmente a coisa é lenta. Mas sim, algumas acabam adotadas. Capriche nos argumentos :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, foi por isso que perguntei rs. Sempre proponho quando há alguma ideia. Depois redijo uma questão.

Comment: Acho que o objetivo deste *post* aqui não era abrir o debate e sim divulgar a campanha. O debate esteve e acho que está aberto no *link* postado na pergunta.

Comment: Ou utilizamos mais o StackOverflow devido à sua base de utilizadores mais alargada. E o 'Português' desta página afasta de certa forma os utilizadores Portuguêses. Pelo menos, falo por mim.

Answer (score 19):

Reaqueci este tópico porque era para ser um início de campanha.

Nós temos ajudado os novatos a entender o site, comentamos como devem fazer para obter uma resposta ou como responder. Precisamos incentivar os votos também. Sem uma pressão, sem exagero, mas precisamos instruir as pessoas que o voto consciente é importante para classificar o conteúdo.

[Leia o que foi debatido antes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2514/101) ([comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2510/vamos-fazer-uma-campanha-para-incentivar-as-pessoas-a-votarem#comment8985_2510)), comece votar mais, e sempre que perceber que é pertinente, incentive as pessoas que ainda não o fazer a votarem. Deixe um comentário amistoso [mostrando a importância do voto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/101). Tenha certeza que ele leu o [tour].

Além dos novatos que não sabem sobre o voto [há quem vote pouco, seja um números absolutos, seja em termos relativos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all).