# Votar em uma boa pergunta ou uma boa resposta é uma forma de incentivo?

Tags: debate

A minha questão é se votar em boas perguntas, perguntas completas e de acordo com as regras da comunidade ou mesmo respostas nestas mesmas boas condições eu estaria incentivando o usuário novo ou antigo da comunidade a continuar no caminho para melhorar o conteúdo do SOpt.

Estou no caminho correto ou quase lá ou mesmo no caminho contrário?

Comment: **Relacionado:** https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2632/3635, é importante votar, mas o melhor de tudo é votar consciente! :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ao passar o mouse por cima do botão do upvote aparece o seguinte:

> Esta pergunta mostra esforço de pesquisa; é útil e clara

Em respostas:

> Esta resposta é útil

Ou seja, você deveria estar votando por isso.

Ao postar uma pergunta, mesmo se não receber uma resposta, ver a pontuação dela subindo para +1, +2, etc é recompensador, me incentiva. Digo o mesmo acerca das respostas. Acredito que o mesmo valha para todos.

Por outro lado, fico frustrado quando posto uma pergunta ou resposta e sou sumariamente ignorado. Isso é desincentivador. Pior ainda é quando recebe-se voto negativo sem explicação nenhuma.

Entretanto, mesmo que ninguém vote contra ou a favor, se receber algum comentário do tipo "discordo disso", "não é bem isso o que eu queria" ou "não entendi o que você quer", mesmo se forem um pouco frustrantes, já é bem melhor do que o silêncio absoluto.

É verdade que já sou um usuário experiente no site e 1 ou 2 votos a mais ou a menos em uma pergunta ou resposta não vão ter nenhum impacto sério para mim. Entretanto, para quem está começando no site, um ou dois votos podem ser muito significativos.

Além disso, se a pessoa se esforçou em fazer uma pergunta ou resposta completa, detalhada, sem encher linguiça, sem omitir detalhes importantes e perfeitamente dentro do escopo do site, não tenho receio nenhum em dar o meu +1, afinal de contas ela fez exatamente o que deveria fazer neste site.

Por outro lado, para perguntas e respostas desleixadas, incompletas, superficiais, vagas, confusas e mal-redigidas, não dou voto a favor. Muitos usuários não tem receio nenhum de tacar o -1 lá.

Comment: Minha opinião bate muito com a sua e fiquei na dúvida se estava no caminho ou deveria somente votar nos assuntos que me ajudaram ou que domino.

Comment: Compartilho sua opinião, e acho que grande parte dos usuários compartilham. É bem frustrante você dedicar um tempo para postar algo com qualidade e ficar no silêncio absoluto, seja sem o feedback do autor da pergunta a respeito de sua resposta ou de obter uma resposta a sua duvida.

Answer (score 9):

O *alt-text* do botão de voto positivo diz:

> Esta pergunta mostra esforço de pesquisa; é útil e clara

Esses devem ser os motivos de todo e qualquer voto positivo.

Já se o usuário vai se sentir incentivado ou não, depende de cada pessoa. Mas a literatura na psicologia mostra que quando você atrela um score (como a reputação) a qualquer coisa, as pessoas tendem a se comportar de modo a aumentar seu score pessoal. Talvez seja comportamento condicionado por jogar tanto videogame quando eu era criança, mas comigo funciona, me dar um voto positivo é que nem dar um biscoito pra um cachorro.

Comment: Verdade e concordo contigo, é melhor continuar a incentivar.

Comment: Seria ótimo se todos seguissem apenas isso ao votar, e não se "fulano que postou é legal ou não"