# Por que existe tanta restrição no SOpt em relação ao SOen?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento

Há uns dias atrás fiz [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316999/como-importar-um-projeto-do-wordpress-se-eu-s%C3%B3-tenho-os-arquivos-brutos?noredirect=1#comment641524_316999) igual [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667195/how-to-setup-existing-wordpress-project-on-xampp) feita no Stack Overflow EN. Porém, ao contrário da pergunta no site EN, a minha pergunta foi negativada e sinalizada como fora do escopo. 
Porque isso acontece só aqui no Brasil?

Várias perguntas técnicas minhas, que eu tenho certeza que iriam ajudar muitas pessoas, acabam sendo negativadas ou fechadas pois não tem código fonte, sendo que, a resposta em si não necessariamente precisa de código às vezes é algo mais relacionado com configuração, estrutura de pastas e etc.

É errado perguntar assim? Eu fiz exatamente a mesma pergunta. E por fim, isso não prejudica o desenvolvimento do site PT?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/5878)

Comment: Só pra constar, a pergunta que vc citou é 2012, naquela época o SOen nem era tão exigente quanto a clareza, agora sobre a sua pergunta, vc cita um tal xml, sinceramente eu não consegui entender que xml é esse, fora que Wordpress eu já trabalhei, a unica coisa que eu fazia para migrar era um backup do banco de dados e colocar os arquivos no novo servidor via FTP e configurar as permissões de pasta (que é coisa de linux) para as pastas necessarias, como as de add-ons. Do meu ponto de vista sua pergunta esta bem dificil de entender, se vc puder explicar que tipo de migração vc deseja eu...

Comment: ... tenho certeza que poderei lhe ajudar.

Comment: Está longe de ser a mesma, longe de ser a mesma época, e de qualquer forma lá passa muita coisa porque ninguém vê.

Comment: Bom, como eu sou aberto a aceitar o erro... analisei direito e é verdade não tem muita relação, e com a outra pergunta feita "Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com" entendi que um não necessariamente segue as regras do outro. Vou refazer a pergunta no SO PT com mais detalhes para que possa ajudar a galera com essa dificuldade e me ajudar né...

Comment: Só ratificando o comentário do @Maniero: que a pergunta no SOen é de 2012. Isso é antes da política de evitar se tornar uma wasteland, ainda na época do declínio da qualidade do SOen

Comment: Só não entendi foi os -4 nesta pergunta. Acho que as pessoas confundem com o negativar quando não se está de acordo, quando é o caso... Mas não é este caso. A pergunta é pertinente, podendo ou não concordar com o pensamento do utilizador, não merece 4 negativos com toda a certeza.

Comment: @JorgeB. muito obrigado pelas palavras era exatamente o que eu pensava... o engraçado é que é tanta a vontade de fazer uma comunidade melhor, que é mais facil negativar a pergunta do que dizer "então, redija uma pergunta de acordo com as regras do site"

Comment: @JorgeB. aqui é o meta - os votos sempre significaram concordância ou discordância - eu não votei nessa pergunta, mas também não concordo com ela e acho totalmente justificado os votos que ela recebeu; e já foi dito diversas vezes: não há problema algum em ter downvotes numa questão no meta - tampouco faz sentido deleta-la por conta disso (o que muitos fazem)

Comment: @Blogueira supostamente não é assim que funciona o meta. A concordância ou discordância ocorre quando há alguma matéria para concordar ou discordar. Se um utilizador faz um pergunta e quer apenas uma resposta não faz sentido concordar. Tipo eu não concordo com a tua pergunta?! Isso tem muita pouca lógica.

Comment: @JorgeB. pois é - é muito difícil definir com o que está se concordando ou discordando; mais difícil ainda é impor tal definição em quem for votar; eu posso discordar por vários motivos: porque a pergunta não é útil e talvez não devesse existir; porque ela já foi feita diversas vezes e uma busca já traria a resposta ao AP; porque os argumentos são falsos ou fracos e, por que não, por conta da pergunta retórica: "não prejudica o desenvolvimento do site?" - por simplesmente achar que não

Comment: @Blogueira claro que sim, você pode fazer isso. Eu só dei a minha opinião quanto ao assunto em questão. Acho que é sempre pior negativar que escrever um comentário, pela conotação que têm os votos negativos. Além disso, embora que meio generalizando, o AP usa uma pergunta especifica para colocar a sua dúvida, nesse caso de pergunta especifica acho que deve ser discutido caso a caso, não devemos generalizar. Até poderia ser uma pergunta boa que por acaso tivesse sido negativa de forma errada. Dai eu achar que esta pergunta no meta tem a sua pertinência. Mas não deixa de ser só a minha opinião.

Comment: Senhores: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4788/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado "Reza a lenda que no Meta o voto negativo nas perguntas devia ser usado somente quando discordamos de um pedido de novo-recurso". Mas se for ao site principal, por exemplo, também deveria ser +1 para bom conteúdo e as vezes vê-se +1 por gostar do AP ou por outros mil motivos que não a qualidade. Foi muito por este tipo de comportamento que eu me afastei um bocado do SOpt.

Comment: Defendo de que ao votar -1 deveria abrir um campo para postar o motivo. Assim tanto o motivo quanto a pessoa que votou ficariam expostos. Com isso ajudaria não apenas a comunidade mas o usuário a fazer perguntas melhores. Voto anônimo não é bom nem no Congresso Nacional, porque as pessoas costumam se esconder atrás dele.

Comment: @sam aqui o campo eh minado, monitorado e controlado, longe da ciência do Monjolo Franciscano, por isso, essa ação opera em ups pra uns poucos e downs para muitos  e muitas vezes

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado só para lembrar que nem sempre é "por que", no caso de ser em pt_PT é "porque" mesmo. Neste caso está correto porque a pergunta parece ser em pt_BR mas é só para relembrar ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. , nossa! Nem imaginava isso! Pensei que fosse um ponto convergente de português, [mas não](https://www.infoenem.com.br/ora-pois-os-porques-em-portugal-sao-diferentes/)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tem isso no [portuguese.se]: [Como usar corretamente “por que”, “por quê”, “porque” e “porquê”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1/153)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As perguntas são diferentes: No SOen, o autor fala que pegou um projeto, configurou o banco, consegue acessar a interface de administração, só tem um problema pra exibir o conteúdo...ainda que não muito clara, mas já ficou mais fácil pra quem tem experiência no wordpress ajuda-lo.

A sua pergunta, só diz que baixou os arquivos do FTP e quer funcionar...
Qualquer um, mesmo tendo experiência com wordpress teria que ficar te questionando:

Qual banco está utilizando? Exportou o banco? Importou? Estava funcionando no ambiente anterior? Consegue acessar o wp-admin? etc...

Muita gente aqui no SOpt tem boa vontade pra ajudar, até porque, ajudando também aprendemos, mas perguntas onde teria que ficar adivinhando o problema é complicado... perde-se muito tempo.

Há instruções de como fazer perguntas e qual é o escopo da comunidade:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Sem falar que gera 200 comentários que poderiam ser evitados se a pergunta fosse suficientemente clara.