# Relação entre votos e Primeira Publicação/Respostas Tardias

Tags: suporte, votos, filas-de-análise

Por que quando atinge o limite diário de votos, bloqueia a análise de Primeira Publicação e Repostas Tardias?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Porque entre as atividades para se fazer nos itens constantes nessas filas, uma delas é votar na postagem, na verdade uma das mais prováveis já que [o voto é das coisas mais importantes do nosso site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/101). Se você não pode fazer isso, não tem o cardápio completo das ações e tem gente que pode ficar tentada a fazer qualquer outra coisa só para "cumprir" a análise, enquanto que o certo nesse caso seria pular. Então para evitar abusos é melhor não permitir fazer essa análise nesse tempo.

Comment: Entendo e concordo que o voto é importante. Porém, não vejo necessidade de bloquear, visto que a análise da primeira publicação é tão "disputada" e nem sempre os usuários que analisam votam a favor ou contra.

Comment: Mas nas vezes que essa é a ação correta, ele não poderá tomá-la, então sua capacidade está capenga. É como a pessoa ser juiz de futebol e ser cego.

Comment: Gostei da analogia :) Nem em [futebol de cegos](http://www.brasil2016.gov.br/pt-br/paraolimpiadas/modalidades/futebol-de-cinco) o juiz é cego.

Comment: @bfavaretto é boa, mas a melhor mesmo seria não ter os cartões vermelho e amarelo, ou o apito. Mas agora a piada ficou sem graça :)

Comment: @Taisbevalle não sei se entendi mal seu comentário, mas o objetivo da fila é justamente que esse tipo de post seja analisado rapidamente pelos membros com mais experiencia, não existe disputa de quem vota mais ou menos, claro que tem alguns que abusam do recurso, votando simplesmente pra ganhar medalha, mas isso é um caso a parte que ocorre com um numero pequeno.