# Realmente fora de escopo as perguntas sobre Angular?

Tags: debate

### Pergunta Fechada por estar fora de escopo?

> **Fechada. Essa pergunta é fora de escopo e não está atualmente
> aceitando respostas.**

Como pode uma pergunta sobre Angular estar fora de escopo? A pergunta está mínima, completa e verificável.

[Preciso de ajuda com FormGoup, pois não consigo obter os dados que desejo. Alguém consegue me ajudar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/522954/83882)

## Mínima, completa e verificável?

> **Mínimo:** Quanto maior o código, menor a chance de alguém enxergar o
> problema.

Frameworks como Angular precisam de um contexto de diferentes arquivos para se encontrar uma solução. Isso pode envolver:

- Arquivos de um ou mais módulos;
- Arquivos de um ou mais Componentes em TypeScript;
- Arquivos de um ou mais Componentes em HTML;
- Arquivos de um ou mais CSS;

Isso é comum e acontece no StackOverflow EN (https://stackoverflow.com/q/39152071/7934535)

> **Completo:** Certifique-se de incluir toda a informação necessária para reproduzir
> o problema:

Na pergunta demonstrada, foi colocado o arquivo de Componentes em TypeScript e HTML.

> **Verificável:** Para ajudá-lo a resolver seu problema, as pessoas
> primeiro precisam comprovar que ele existe

O problema é claro, acessar informações do [FormGoup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).

Isso acontece com outras perguntas fechadas relacionadas ao Angular:

- [Somar dinamicamente todos os campos do FormBuilder. Front-end Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/522910/83882)
- [A parte do jQuery do meu materialize não funciona no Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/522494/83882)
- [Erro criando routerLink Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'trip-auth-module' criando um routerLink](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/521407/83882)
- [Como preencher dois formArraym um dentro do outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/519250/83882)

Comment: Não vou analisar a fundo porque não domino a tecnologia, mas qualquer pergunta que tenha "Preciso de ajuda" no título, e ainda um "Alguém consegue me ajudar?" já tem uns 99% de chances de não ser uma boa pergunta. Se fosse boa a pessoa destacaria o problema específico dela em vez de pedir ajuda. O mesmo vale para variações como "alguma ideia?" ou "o que está acontecendo?" (um pouco menos) e coisas assim. Também não ajuda qualquer pergunta que tenha dezenas de linhas de código, provavelmente viola o MCVE, por cima vi coisas irrelevantes. Muitas vezes pequenos detalhes fazem toda diferença.

Comment: De qualquer forma, não faz sentido perguntar se Angular está no escopo, [claro que está](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bangular%5d%20is%3aquestion), o problema não é a tecnologia, é a pergunta.

Comment: É verdade @Maniero, concordo que muitas das perguntas com o título "Preciso de Ajuda" costumam não ser muito boas.

Comment: Uma coisa que muita gente não entende é que o MCVE existe para fazer a pessoa se esforçar, se preocupar com a questão, para ele mexer no código antes de submeter, tentar achar uma solução, não tratar o código dela como uma porcaria qualquer que ela achou na rua, é para ela cuidar, para mostrar que sabe o que está fazendo, apesar do problema encontrado. Então ela não deve colocar o código todo, só o que for relevante para a questão. "Ah, mas ela não sabe fazer isso", então o problema não é o que está na pergunta, é ele pulando etapas, fingindo que que está programando, e cai no "faça pra mim"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Você se confundiu um pouco.

Essa é a pergunta que foi fechada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1ad27ee7-1f1e-4cc1-9509-077068efe083/view-source

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o motivo do fechamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pergunta foi fechada como sendo de baixa qualidade pois a mesma exige a cópia caractere por caractere de uma imagem para poder replicar um exemplo que pode ou não estar completo para ai iniciar os testes que levam o processo de produção da resposta.
Em [28/11/16 às 19:02](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5485/) já era uma preocupação pergunta cujo o código fosse publicado como imagem.

## Filas e privilégios

Quando chegar a 3.000 pontos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você ganha o privilégio de [Votar para suspender ou reabrir perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

Aqui a opção que surge nas perguntas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o menu de ferramentas de analise:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que nos leva as interfaces das filas de analises de publicações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que uma pergunta fechada é editada ela é submetida a uma nova rodada da fila de analise de reabertura onde precisa do voto de reabertura de três(3) usuários do site com mais de 3.000 pontos de reputação para ser reaberta.

Então a pergunta que hoje está em questão não é mais a mesma pergunta que foi fechada e o momento em que escrevo ainda não foi dado nenhum voto de reabertura em favor dessa questão.

## O que você pode fazer

Como não tem ainda pontuação para participar das analises de fechamento e reabertura você tem as seguintes opções:

- [Vote na questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente), o voto é a segunda coisa mais importante para os sites SE. Vote e nos ajude a destacar a qualidade das perguntas e respostas com seu voto.
- Use os comentários e converse com o autor da pergunta e sugira ou faça edições no sentido de melhorar o post e esclarecer os pontos obscuros.
- Deixe no campo de comentários, instruções para os analistas indicando o que evoluiu e o que a pergunta melhorou.
- Use o [nosso chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) para conscientizar as pessoas que ali tem uma pergunta clara, respondível e que deve ser reaberta.
- Faça um post aqui no META, mas ao invés de questionar equivocadamente o fechamento(que foi justo), faça uma analise técnica sobre o conteúdo da pergunta e defenda, baseado no conteúdo dessa análise, o argumento do porque a pergunta deve ser reaberta.

## A conclusão

A conclusão é que está faltando a participação dos usuários nos processos internos do site as pessoas estão focada apenas em perguntar e responder, mas entre esses dois extremos existe todo um aparato voltado ao aprimoramento de conteúdo que as pessoas não estão usando enquanto as perguntas ficam paradas.

Comment: Simples, direto, objetivo e muito claro

Comment: Ótima explicação, apesar que preciso dizer que os comentários nas perguntas fechadas foram bem claros e objetivos também.

Comment: Mt boa resposta.