# Justificativa para fechamento de perguntas fora de escopo

Tags: debate, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Essa pergunta foi fechada: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/543788/valores-escritos-na-mem%C3%B3ria-stack-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-deletados-ap%C3%B3s-o-encerramento-de-uma). Eu não entendi o motivo para isso e fui consultar a "atividade da pergunta" e foi anotado que "[a pergunta] Não é adequada para este site" e que estava "[fora de escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". A questão não é baseada em opiniões, versa sobre um assunto específico e um exemplo ilustrativo (mínimo e reprodutível) é fornecido. Também não é uma duplicata e uma questão semelhante, e bastante famosa, consta no Stack Overflow em Inglês: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). Por fim, é sobre "um problema específico de programação", conforme recomendado. Todos os links fornecidos não me esclareceram sobre o fechamento da pergunta.

Dessa forma, fiz uma sinalização sobre a pergunta indicando que necessitava atenção:

> Poderia ser informado, por gentileza, por que essa pergunta se
> encontra fechada? Me parece se enquadrar nos tópicos do site:
> pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. No Stack Overflow em inglês há uma
> pergunta bastante famosa sobre essa mesma questão
> (stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/…). Muito obrigado.

Como resposta obtive:

> rejeitado - Usar sinalizações padrões ajuda-nos priorizar problemas e
> resolvê-las mais rápido. Por favor familiarize-se com a lista de
> sinalizações padrões: veja O que é Sinalizar?

Eu sigo sem saber o motivo do fechamento da pergunta. Eu gostaria de saber qual o procedimento adequado a ser adotado quando houver discordância quanto ao fechamento. Também me parece que "fora de escopo" é uma classificação demasiadamente ampla. Dessa forma, não poderia ser anotado o motivo específico para fechamento da pergunta? Muito obrigado desde já.

Acrescento que eu não sou o autor da pergunta, mas da resposta a ela. Porém, sabendo especificamente o problema da pergunta, isso me permite evitar que no futuro as minhas próprias perguntas incorram no mesmo problema.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: Relacionado a [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/137387), [Realmente fora de escopo as perguntas sobre Angular?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8649/137387), [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387), [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101), [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow) e link de pesquisa https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perguntas-fechadas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa é a pergunta original, a que foi fechada antes de ser editada:

[image: Pergunta fechada parte A]
[image: Pergunta fechada parte B]

No link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/543788/revisions é possível acompanhar o histórico da pergunta e verificar que todo o código que acompanha a pergunta foi publicado como imagens e essa foi o motivo que fundamentou o  meu voto de fechamento como pergunta de baixa qualidade por não atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade:

[image: Quadro de fechamento com texto não atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade destacado]

No [**Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas), datado de 28/11/2016, existe uma seção intitulada [**Postar código como imagem**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485) onde são detalhados os problemas e dificuldades que um usuário cujo esteja disposto a responder a pergunta passa quando o código está publicado como imagem.

Na publicação [**Postar mensagem de erro como imagem**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7816/postar-mensagem-de-erro-como-imagem/7817#7817), datada de 31/05/2019, apresenta outros motivos além desse o do porque devem ser evitada a publicação de código e logs como imagens.

O que mais me chama atenção é que o autor da pergunta como um programador não consiga perceber que ao publicar um código como imagem está obrigando um outro ser humano que queira testar o seu código a transcrevê-lo, digitando caractere por caractere o que é uma atividade trabalhosa e propensa a erros.

Em resumo desde 2016 perguntas publicadas com o código contido em imagens são fechadas. Como já foi [publicado aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8649/137387):

> Toda vez que uma pergunta fechada é editada ela é submetida a uma nova
> rodada da fila de analise de reabertura onde precisa do voto de
> reabertura de três(3) usuários do site com mais de 3.000 pontos de
> reputação para ser reaberta.

E no momento em escrevo essa resposta, a pergunta se encontra na fila de análise de reabertura e recebeu apenas um voto para reabertura.

Comment: Eu agradeço o retorno, Augusto. Como você frisou, é evidente que a postagem de uma imagem é problemática, tanto que fiz a transcrição pra código. Entretanto, o problema do código estar em imagem, pelo menos a mim, não me parece se enquadrar na classificação "fora de escopo". Por isso, achei que tivesse um problema nos fundamentos da pergunta.

Comment: Caso seja possível, no futuro, acredito que seria útil anotar no fechamento especificamente essa questão da imagem. Caso eu tivesse visto, compreenderia de imediato, e não teria aberto qualquer sinalização. Novamente, a sugestão que faço é baseada na minha opinião do que seria o melhor. É claro que "o melhor" pode ser considerado diferente pelo consenso da maioria.

Comment: Também gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de me posicionar discordando do fechamento de uma pergunta. Talvez o caminho adotado pelo site seja deixar ao cargo de quem tem pontuação de fato para votar pela reabertura da questão. Porém, gostaria de ter certeza.

Comment: São limitada as opções de fechamento, não temos essa flexibilidade. O que poderia ser feito é uso do comentário, porém são uma média de 150 perguntas diárias para analisar e somos poucos que fazemos a curadoria do site,

Comment: Sobre as opções de fechamento, eu não sabia. Pensei que pudesse ser escrito um texto personalizado (apaguei o comentário anterior porque entendi errado o que você disse).

Comment: Hoje somos um 10 usuários mais os moderadores que tocamos adiante o site. Ficando difícil comentar em todas as publicações ainda mais ainda que estamos mexendo com o ego das pessoas e a maioria dos que vem aqui acham que sabem algo que os outros não sabem e as vezes sem quer acabamos mostrando a realidade para pessoa e essa acaba por desencadear um conflito.

Comment: Eu entendo perfeitamente, Augusto. E lamento por essa situação, tanto da falta de pessoal para o trabalho como do ego. Eu fiz o post aqui para realmente entender qual era o problema porque eu não tinha entendido. Sabendo que "fora de escopo" abarca um leque amplo de problemas, agora não faço mais a sinalização.

Comment: Quando discordar do fechamento de uma pergunta primeiro passo é comentar na publicação  pedindo esclarecimento da causa. Volta e meia aparecerá alguém para esclarecer. Segundo passo é editar para melhorar a pergunta como fez(estou propenso a votar para reabrir a pergunta lá site principal). Terceiro passo é [o nosso chat oficial](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) conversando diretamente com a comunidade. E o ultimo passo é trazer aqui para o meta uma defesa técnica da pergunta mostrando o porque a pergnta deve ser reaberta.

Comment: Anotado, Augusto. Farei isso nas próximas vezes. Muito obrigado pela atenção aí.